# Restoring SQL Server 2005 database using C#. Rollback issue

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, database-restore

Hi I'm just starting to learn C#. I am trying to restore a .bak file. However I am getting the error. Exclusive access cannot be obtained because the database is in use.

I did my research [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldisasterrecovery/thread/aad41cbb-10cb-4109-9e55-aab048bbeb9d) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183686/how-to-gain-exclusive-access-to-sql-server-2005-db-to-restore) both says I have to perform a rollback. I do not know how to apply rollback in my restore code.

```
    public void RestoreDatabase(String RestorePath)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=RITZEL-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;User ID=NNIT-Admin;Password=password;Initial Catalog=master;");
            ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(sqlCon);
            Server sqlServer = new Server(connection);

            Restore restoreDB = new Restore();

            restoreDB.Database = "NNIT DB";
            restoreDB.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
            restoreDB.Devices.AddDevice(RestorePath, DeviceType.File);

            restoreDB.ReplaceDatabase = true; // will overwrite any existing DB     
            restoreDB.NoRecovery = false; // NoRecovery = true;

            restoreDB.SqlRestore(sqlServer);

            MessageBox.Show("Restored");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + " " + ex.InnerException);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SMO you can set user access and rollback like this:

```
Server sqlServer = new Server(connection);

Database db = sqlServer.Databases["DbToRestore"];

if (db != null)
{
    sqlServer.KillAllProcesses(db.Name);
    db.DatabaseOptions.UserAccess = DatabaseUserAccess.Multiple;
    db.Alter(TerminationClause.RollbackTransactionsImmediately);
}

Restore restoreDB = new Restore();
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ALTER DATABASE yourdatabasename SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE", sqlConn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Where will I put that? Before Restore restoreDB = new Restore();?

Comment: Yes it should kill all connections to the database

Comment: Incorrect syntaxt near the keyword 'SET' and 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression or an xmlnamespaces clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon. Incorrect syntax near 'IMMEDIATE'

Comment: Make sure you're quoting your multi work database name e.g. [NNIT DB] with square brackets