# Automatically Update Field in Database

Tags: oracle, triggers, view, ora-04091

I'd like to automatically update a database column with an aggregate of another column.
There are three tables involved:

```
T_RIDER
  RIDER_ID
  TMP_PONYLIST
  ...

T_RIDER_PONY
  RIDER_ID
  PONY_ID

T_PONY
  PONY_ID
  PONY_NAME
  ...
```

`T_RIDER` and `T_PONY` have an *n:m* relationship via `T_RIDER_PONY`.
`T_RIDER` and `T_PONY` have some more columns but only `TMP_PONYLIST` and `PONY_NAME` are relevant here.

`TMP_PONYLIST` is a semicolon spararated list of `PONY_NAMES`, imagine something like `"Twisty Tail;Candy Cane;Lucky Leaf"`.
I'd like to keep this field up to date no matter what happens to `T_RIDER_PONY` or `T_PONY`.

My first idea was to have triggers on `T_RIDER_PONY` and `T_PONY`. 
The problem is that it seems to be impossible to read `T_RIDER_PONY` within the trigger, I always get `ORA-04091`. I found some hints about working with three triggers and package variables, but this sounds way too complicated.

Maybe you think I'd better change the schema or get rid of `TMP_PONYLIST` completely.
These are options but not the topic of this question.
For the moment **I'm only interested in answers that don't require any change to my applications** (no application works with the tables directly, only views, so trickery with views is allowed).

So, how can I keep `TMP_PONYLIST` up to date automatically?
How to concatenate the string is an interesting subproblem I also have not yet found an elegant solution for.

I'm using Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bi.

**UPDATE**

I like the idea of using a materialized view.
What I have is:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW
  V_TMP_PONYLIST 
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH COMPLETE ON COMMIT
AS SELECT 
  R.RIDER_ID, string_agg(P.PONY_NAME) AS TMP_PONYLIST
FROM
  T_PONY P, T_RIDER R, T_RIDER_PONY RP
WHERE 
  P.PLOTGROUP_ID=RP.PLOTGROUP_ID AND
  R.QUEUE_ID=RP.QUEUE_ID 
GROUP BY R.RIDER_ID;
```

`string_agg` is not shown because it is long and the I think it is not relevant.

It won't compile with `ON COMMIT`, I get `ORA-12054`.
As I understand the documentation aggregates are only forbidden with 
`REFRESH FAST`, so what's the problem here?

**UPDATE**
Vincents and Tonys answers were different but both helpful.
I accepted Tonys but be sure to read Vincents answer also.

Comment: I would advise against storing multiple values ("Twisty Tail;Candy Cane;Lucky Leaf") in a single column...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to read the T_RIDER_PONY table in the trigger?  You will have either inserted or deleted a row, so all the trigger needs to do is look up the pony name in T_PONY and update table T_RIDER, either appending the name to or removing it from TMP_PONYLIST like this

```
create trigger t_rider_pony_trg 
after insert or delete on t_rider_pony
for each row
begin
   if inserting then
      select pony_name
      into   l_pony_name
      where  pony_id = :new.pony_id;

      update t_rider
      set    tmp_ponylist = tmp_ponylist || ';' || l_pony_name
      where  rider_id = :new.rider_id;
   elsif deleting then
      select pony_name
      into   l_pony_name
      where  pony_id = :old.pony_id;

      update t_rider
      set    tmp_ponylist = ltrim ( 
                               rtrim ( 
                                  replace(';' || tmp_ponylist || ';',
                                          ';' || l_pony_name || ';',
                                          ';'),
                                  ';', ';')
      where  rider_id = :old.rider_id;
   end if;
end;
```

That update in the delete section is rather unpleasant I admit; it might be preferable to use utilities like apex_util.string_to_table and apex_util.table_to_string to deal with it! See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381231/hidden-features-in-oracle#381380) for details.

Comment: +1 Cool solution, I thought string manipulation was way too comlicated, but your solution is really nice. At the moment tmp_ponylist is sorted. Do you think it would be difficult to extend your solution that it keeps tmp_ponylist sorted?

Comment: It would be possible to sort the list, but I think you'd need to use either a temporary table or a user-defined type to store it in and select back from in order.  Or write yourself some bubble-sort code to work on a PL/SQL collection!

Comment: I don't think this will work in a multi-user environment.
  User A inserts a row trigger updates T_Rider;
  User B inserts a row, doesn't see A's change; A blocks B's update;
  A commits, releases lock, B updates;
  B commits, A's changes gone

Comment: @Daniel, I don't think so: I didn't SELECT the current value from T_RIDER and then update it, I just updated it.  Once A commits and releases the lock, B gets the row to update and sees A's change before making its own.

Comment: It can fail on mutating table with multi-table inserts and updates through join views, and maybe get deadlock issues when dealing with concurrent non-single row inserts/updates. Look into having tmp_ponylist in a separate on commit materialized view.

Answer (score 3):

the information on the column `TMP_PONYLIST` is redundant (it exists somewhere else). You will get into all sorts of problems to maintain it (No solution will work correctly in a multi-user environment unless there is some sort of locking mechanism).

In a normalized model you would simply drop this column from the physical model. If you need the information, you could use a view, for example with Oracle 11gR2:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW rider_v AS
SELECT rider_id, /*...,*/
       (SELECT listagg(p.pony_name, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY p.pony_name)
          FROM t_pony p
          JOIN t_rider_pony rp ON (p.pony_id = rp.pony_id)
         WHERE rp.rider_id = r.rider_id) tmp_ponylist
  FROM t_rider r;
```

See [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076011/how-can-multiple-rows-be-concatenated-into-one-in-oracle-without-creating-a-store) for example of string aggregation before 11gR2.

Comment: TMP_PONYLIST was introduced for performance reasons. We may get rid of TMP_PONYLIST but I am still exploring the other options. I like the idea of using a view, but it needs to be a materialize one. See my update of the question.