# HTTP Post Request giving NULL in Android

Tags: android, apache, android-activity, http-post

I am trying to send some data on an API. However my APP isn't giving any     response. Neither giving any error nor getting stopped. Its like nothing just happened. I am bit new to android so kindly guide. Besides I know HTTPClient and other imports have become deprecated.

```
public void makePostRequest()
{
    class makePostRequestAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://103.226.216.209/finger_varification/api/finger_verification");
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(7);
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sec_key", "2af8b9d956c39d2d52c46c2a02a978d1"));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cnic", "3520214037921"));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("imei_no", "864121017028886"));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("device_name", "FingerMap5"));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("finger_index",index ));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("finger_template", "sdsd"));//model1.toString()));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("template_type", "RAW_IMAGE"));

            try {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // log exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            //making POST request.
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                // write response to log

                Log.d("Http Post Response:", response.toString());
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // Log exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Log exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if(result.equals("working")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HTTP POST is working...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid POST req...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Hi @Muhammad Abdullah, do you have the following on your manifest file? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get the body of the response

```
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
String response_body = reader.readLine();
Log.d("Http Post Response:", response_body);
```

By the way, **HttpPost** and **HttpResponse** is deprecated on API 23, use **[HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client)** instead

Comment: Exactly deprecated means? I guess it will work. What do you think? moreover...I am not sure how to send and receive using HttpURLConnection....since i have 7 strings to send.

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullah: Meaning of deprecated is explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111774/deprecated-meaning

Short story, it won't be supported for further development/bug fixes in versions after the API 23. Hence you better use HttpURLConnection as mentioned by NaviRamyle

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullah, in regards of HttpURLConnection, I took this piece of code from my personal small projects. `URL url = new URL(uri[0]);
                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    // The request will automatically be fired on demand when you want to get
                    // any information about the HTTP response
                    httpURLConnection.connect();
                    int statusCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();`

Comment: `if (statusCode == 200) {
                        BufferedReader inbf = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
                        String inputLine;
                        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

                        while ((inputLine = inbf.readLine()) != null) {
                            response.append(inputLine);
                        }
                        responseString = response.toString();
                        inbf.close();
                    }`