# Absolute value of float in ocaml

Tags: ocaml, utop

When I use the function `abs_float`, Merlin (running in emacs) tells me:

`Warning 3: deprecated: Core.Std.abs_float
[since 2014-10] Use [Float]`

(The code still compiles, though.) What is this trying to tell me? I've tried Float.abs and similar variants without success. When I try `#require "Float"` and `open Float` in utop, I get `No such package` and `unbound module` errors.

I know it's trivial to write an absolute value function oneself, but I'm still interested in knowing how to do this the "right" way.

Comment: To use `Float.abs`, put `open Core.Std` at the beginning of your code. (you should do that to all your files that are using _Core_).  For utop, use `#require "core.top"` before `open Core.Std`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is :

```
 Core.Std.Float.abs (-6.0)
```

Answer (score 2):

> What is this trying to tell me?

The warning message that you're getting:

```
Warning 3: deprecated: Core.Std.abs_float
```

is telling you that the function `abs_float` has been [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111774/deprecated-meaning). This basically means that, while the function still *works*, it's no longer supported and advises you to not use it anymore.

When you see the message

```
Use [Float]
```

It's telling you that the newer version that you should be using is in the `Float` module. This is in the context of `Core.Std`, so instead of using

```
Core.Std.abs_float
```

you should use

```
Core.Std.Float.abs
```