# Google Calendar Gadget deprecation message

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

When loading a gadget I wrote, I received the following message:

"Warning: Calendar sidebar gadgets are now deprecated and will soon cease to be supported"

Does this mean that soon I won't be able to use my gadgets anymore? Or just that Google won't help anymore with gadget issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means support will cease but the feature may still remain. Additional reference in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111774/deprecated-meaning):

> In the process of authoring computer software, its standards or
>   documentation, deprecation is a status applied to software features to
>   indicate that they should be avoided, typically because they have been
>   superseded

However, there are times that deprecation also means that [sometime at a future date, it will be shutdown](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/auth-migration#timetable). So follow the docs and avoid using it.

Comment: Is it known whether an alternative approach for creating Google Calendar add ons?  Or is it that going forward the UI for any app integration will not be shown within Google Calendar?

Comment: I'm guessing Chrome Extension is the alternative - although limits any development to Chrome unfortunately.  I also see 
"Gmail Addons" is a new alternative to Gmail Gadgets so maybe something similar will happen for calendar.