# Firestore enablePersistence deprecated

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hovering over the method it says to use `Settings.persistenceEnabled`

[image]

I was already using that for mobile like so:

```
db.settings = const Settings(persistenceEnabled: true);
```

Looking inside `persistenceEnabled` I see

[image]

On their [documentation page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline), which **isn't deprecated** (at least for now), I see exactly the same code I was using:

[image]

**Is it still possible to handle firestore cache for web now? How?**

More info:

I'm in flutter and I updated recently to "cloud_firestore: ^4.15.5"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like the documentation is saying you should use **both** forms if you want persistence enabled on both web and mobile.

[Deprecation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111774/deprecated-meaning) doesn't mean that the API doesn't work at all - it just means that it might stop working in the future.  My guess is that the deprecation for Flutter just means that you should be aware that the way persistence is configured for web right now might change in the future, possibly in relation to some other library that the Flutter SDK depends on.

You can be sure that the developers of the Flutter SDK will simply remove any APIs if they are known not to work at all, or at least make that very clear in the API docs.