# load data from text file to table by using sql loader and load the those record which column no 3 = Null

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, sql-loader

I want to load data from text file to table and those record which `column_m = Null` and filter out reaming record.

When I tried with

```
column_3 = '' 
column_3 = Blanks
```

Both are not working

It's only working with when give the position but my data file is not fixed size, so it will not work.

data file

```
-------------
col 1 | col2 | col 3|
---------------------
1001 |  TM  |RmRK |
1002 |  KL  |21   |
1004 |  KL  |     |
1005 |  KL  |     |
1006 |  MH  |NED  |
```

How should I insert those record which `col3 = NULL` and filter the reaming record?

Comment: Try where column_3 is null

Comment: column_3 is null also not working ... getting syntax error

Comment: Create an external table or load this into a staging table and filter from there.

Comment: You need to read line by line and then split by |. This is a good example for how to split the line, it is splitting by , but it is the same principle.

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710589/is-there-a-function-to-split-a-string-in-pl-sql