# How to remove the domain name from an email address in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

If input like this

as input- `abcdxyz@gmail.com` & `pqrstuv@yahoo.com`

and somebody want output like

as output- `abcdxyz` & `pqrstuv`

How can I do this using Oracle?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710589/is-there-a-function-to-split-a-string-in-pl-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your case this will do the job:

```
select regexp_replace('abcdxyz@gmail.com & pqrstuv@yahoo.com','@[a-zA-z0-9.]*','') from dual;
```

It is based on asumption that domain name contains only digits and a-z chars.

Answer (score 0):

If you know all of the possible email addresses (not likely nor robust), you can use the TRIM function:

http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rreftrimfunc.html

More likely, you'll write your own that "rolls" the characters one at a time until it hits the delimiter. A shortish example to this is here (in the split function of the longer example in the accepted answer):

[Is there a function to split a string in PL/SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710589/is-there-a-function-to-split-a-string-in-pl-sql)

A more complex example and discussion on performance is here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20170914140540/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/oracle/1968/splitting-delimited-strings#t=201709141405407224393

Comment: The first link is **not** for the Oracle database but for "JavaDB" aka "Apache Derby".