# PL sql substring issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column as below. there are multiple columns like this with different data.
[image]

I need output like this

[image]

I need values that inside | | symbols. I tried like below But not successes. I am new to PL SQL. Please give some suggestions to this. Do i need a cursor or loop for do this

```
SELECT 
           regexp_substr(profile_value,'\|([^|]+)\|',1,1,NULL,1) 
FROM table1
```

As a result of my query i am getting only **WO_NO=1^**

Comment: The other parts are also between `| |`. Please be clear about what your requirements are. Also please be clear about what didn't work, and please, do provide the input value as text, so people can easily copy it in order to help you.

Comment: At first glance, it looks like you could split the string on `|`, and get the even items in the list that gives you. Maybe you can use one of the solutions of [Is there a function to split a string in PL/SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710589/is-there-a-function-to-split-a-string-in-pl-sql)

Comment: In my query its getting only first value inside the || its correct. But others are not loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I understood it.

```
SQL> with
  2  test (col) as
  3    (select '9D49|WO_NO=1^|WO no: 1;D972|WO_NO=60003^|WO no: 60003;AED1' from dual union all
  4     select '1234|WO_NO=25^|WO no:25;797|WO_NO=26^'                      from dual
  5    ),
  6  temp as
  7    (select regexp_substr(col, '[^|]+', 1, column_value) val,
  8            column_value cv,
  9            col
 10     from test cross join
 11       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 12                           connect by level <= regexp_count(col, '\|') + 1
 13                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 14    )
 15  select listagg(val, ' or ') within group (order by cv) result
 16  from temp
 17  where substr(val, 1, 5) = 'WO_NO'
 18  group by col ;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WO_NO=25^ or WO_NO=26^
WO_NO=1^ or WO_NO=60003^

SQL>
```

Comment: thank you! i can get some part from your one. that WO_NO can be change. so thats why i am trying to get it by inside this | | symbol

Comment: You can set it as a **parameter** in line #17.

Comment: i will try with this. thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Splitting the string into items**

Assuming (for now, stay tuned) that Table1 has a single row, you can write a regular expression and use it in a recursive query to split the string in a single select.

`level` denotes the level of recursion. `regexp_substr` lets you specify the occurrence in the string. `connect by` provides the exit condition: taking the next item, until there is none.

```
select
  level as ItemNr,
  regexp_substr(profile_value, '[^|]+', 1, level) as Item 
from
  Table1
connect by
  regexp_substr(profile_value, '[^|]+', 1, level) is not null
```

**Combining the wanted items into a new string**

You could use `ListAgg` with a `case` condition, to combine only the items where `level` is an even number back into a single string, with the string `' or '` as a separator.

```
select
  listagg(
    case when mod(level, 2) = 0 then
      regexp_substr(profile_value, '[^|]+', 1, level)
    end, ' or ') as Items 
from
  Table1
connect by
  regexp_substr(profile_value, '[^|]+', 1, level) is not null
```

**For multiple rows**

The query above doesn't work well by itself if Table1 has multiple rows. It assumes a single input value. Using yet another trick, `cross apply`, you can make this a subquery that does this transformation for each of the rows of your table.

The query below shows the original `profile_value` column, and the transformed `items` for each of the rows in Table1.

```
select
  t.*, x.*
from
  Table1 t
  cross apply (
    select
      listagg(
        case when mod(level, 2) = 0 then
          regexp_substr(profile_value, '[^|]+', 1, level)
        end, ' or ') as Items
    from 
      dual -- just selecting a single profile_value
    connect by
      regexp_substr(profile_value, '[^|]+', 1, level) is not null
  ) x
```

In the end this works okay for a not to large set of data, but you're storying structured data into a string, and querying this is not very efficient.

If you need to repeat this query a lot, and the number of rows in Table1 is growing, it's probably better to store it in a more structured way.
If this data is coming from an external source, you could dump it in a temporary table, and transform it using the queries of this answer, to write it to a final, better structured table (or tables) for repeated use.

Comment: I tried with your query. its executing more than 3 mins now. stil not getting any results

Comment: How many rows do you have in this table and how long are those column values. It works fine for a small input, but if you have a lot of data, a more optimized stored procedure could be better.

Comment: There are 20 rows in my table.

Comment: I think I assumed you wanted this for a single row. With multiple rows, this gives permutations of all combinations of items into a single string. ayy

Comment: its my fault i will update my question

Comment: In the mean time, I've appended the answer.