# Reverse output of Oracle regexp_replace

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-replace

I've got a variable: `v_NumInOne VARCHAR2(2342) := 234534564567`

Then with the next line I've seperated it, using: `(REGEXP_REPLACE((v_NumInOne), '(....)','\1 ' ));`

The result: `2345 3456 4567`

Now I'd like to reverse the output.

Expected result: `4567 3456 2345`.

Comment: Look also here for a more elegant approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381231/hidden-features-in-oracle.

Comment: @lad2025 that link helped me a lot, thanks!