# SQL Server - What is the date/time of the last inserted row of a table?

Tags: sql-server, timestamp

My fellow programmers did not think to add timestamps to every tables of our outstanding database.

As a result, some tables seem to be outdated, but it is very difficult to say which ones.

Is there any way to get, for each table, the date/time of the last insert command performed against it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the version of SQL server you're using. SQL server 2005 or newer you try looking [here](https://sqlblog.org/2008/05/06/when-was-my-database-table-last-accessed). If its an older server engine you may be out of luck unless someone was proactive enough to use stored procedures and logged updates.

Comment: I'm in luck, i'm using SQL Server 2005 ! :o) Thanks for the link.