# Where can I find TableDiff.exe?

Tags: sql-server

I just found out about the TableDiff tool for SQL Server on the [hidden features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121243/hidden-features-of-sql-server) question and had a full-blown *nerdgasm*. I would like to download the tool, but everywhere I look I am told to look in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\COM\TableDiff.exe`. After looking *everywhere* on my PC (I have SQL Server 2008 Express and SQL Server 2008 installed), I can't find it.

Where I can download the *TableDiff.exe* tool stand-alone?

The [GUI tool](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/03/03/60125.aspx) isn't the droid I'm looking for.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 is version 10.0 not 9.0, so it would be ...\Microsoft SQL Server\100\COM\...

Comment: Thanks, I realised that - found it in C:\Program Files x86\...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My Windows Search is broken, or I'm an idiot. I found it here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\COM\tablediff.exe
```

and NOT here as expected:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\COM
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: I am so sticking with `dir tablediff.exe /s` from now on.

Comment: Yup, Windows Search is crap.  I always use `dir /s` these days.

Comment: @FreshCode I've been using dir but never of /s. Thanks

Comment: When I need to find something on my Windows computer, I use Everything.  It's amazing and really fast  https://www.voidtools.com/downloads/

Answer (score 29):

If you cannot find TableDiff.exe, re-run the SQL Server install and choose REPLICATION support.

TableDiff is officially "Microsoft (R) SQL Server Replication Diff Tool" and will be added when using Replication.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you are running a 64bit OS as mine is located here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\COM\tablediff.exe
```

Comment: I looked there - that folder is just filled with a bunch of DLLs. But I am running a 64-bit machine...let me look deeper.

Comment: As per Svein Fidjestøl's comment below, if you're running 64bit SQL Server, it'll be in C:\Program Files\, not C:\Program Files (x86)\

Answer (score 3):

On Windows with 64-bit SQL Server 2014, `tablediff.exe` is located here:

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\COM\tablediff.exe`

- Replace `120` with `110` for SQL Server 2012, `100` for SQL Server 2008, etc.
- For 32-bit version of SQL Server running on 64-bit Windows, replace `Program Files` with `Program Files (x86)`

Answer (score 2):

tablediff.exe is self defined, if you did not find in your machine, look at someone else machine and grab the exe.

Answer (score 1):

I found it by this path

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\COM
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only find the tablediff.exe application back if you have choses the "SQL Server Replication" feature (Instance Features/Database Engine Services/SQL Server Replication).

I had a few servers where this feature was not installed and then you don't find the executable back.

Comment: Hey Peter, this was covered by [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3909963/6530134) already.