# Loop on all database query in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have multi dbs with same structure I want to loop on them to check this select statment

```
select scan1,scan2,scan3 from customers where ..............
```

the output would be database name if this select has records
like that:

```
db1
db2
db3
```

and so on ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all trying to help me but i found the query and here it is if it can help any one.

```
exec sp_MSforeachdb 
'
if "?" like "Client%" and isnumeric(substring("?",7,4)) = 1 
BEGIN
DECLARE @QueryString NVARCHAR(500)
SET @QueryString = "Select Scan1,Scan2,scan3 from ?.dbo.Customers where Scan1 <> '''' or Scan2 <> '''' or Scan3 <> ''''"
EXEC sp_executesql @QueryString

IF @@RowCount >  0
print "?"
END
'
```

thanks

Comment: Yes this was identified with and other [hidden features](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121243/hidden-features-of-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    Select 'DB1' as DatabaseName From DB1.MyTable Where ...
    UNION
    Select 'DB2' as DatabaseName From DB2.MyTable Where ...
    UNION
    Select 'DB3' as DatabaseName From DB3.MyTable Where ...
    <Add as many more as you need>
)

Select DatabaseName From CTE Where DatabaseName IS NOT NULL
```