# SQL Server Undocumented Stored Procedures and functions

Tags: sql-server, undocumented-behavior

I found there are lots of advanced featured stored procedures in SQL Server which are not documented by the Books Online. I found them from googling. Here are some of them if you have others please share them with me.

Undocumented Stored Procedures in SQL Server

```
sp_checknames
sp_columns_rowset
sp_enumoledbdatasources
sp_fixindex
sp_gettypestring
sp_ms_marksystemobject
sp_msaddguidcolumn
sp_msaddguidindex
sp_msaddlogin_implicit_ntlogin
sp_msadduser_implicit_ntlogin
sp_mscheck_uid_owns_anything
sp_msdbuseraccess
sp_msdbuserpriv
sp_msdependencies
sp_msdrop_object
sp_msforeachdb
sp_msforeachtable
sp_msget_qualified_name
sp_msgettools_path
sp_msgetversion
sp_msguidtostr
sp_mshelpcolumns
sp_mshelpindex
sp_mshelptype
sp_msindexspace
sp_msis_pk_col
sp_mskilldb
sp_msloginmappings
sp_mstablekeys
sp_mstablerefs
sp_mstablespace
sp_msunc_to_drive
sp_msuniquecolname
sp_msuniquename
sp_msuniqueobjectname
sp_msuniquetempname
sp_tempdbspace
sp_who2
xp_delete_file
xp_dirtree
xp_enum_oledb_providers
xp_enumcodepages
xp_enumdsn
xp_enumerrorlogs
xp_enumgroups
xp_fileexist
xp_fixeddrives
xp_get_mapi_default_profile
xp_get_mapi_profiles
xp_getnetname
xp_qv
xp_readerrorlog
xp_regaddmultistring
xp_regdeletekey
xp_regdeletevalue
xp_regenumvalues
xp_regread
xp_regremovemultistring
xp_regwrite
xp_subdirs
xp_varbintohexstr
```

sp_MSforeachtable can be used to loop through all the tables in your databases. Here are some common usages of this useful stored procedure

```
Display the size of all tables in a database
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="EXEC sp_spaceused '?'"


    Display Number of Rows in all Tables in a database
    
    EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'SELECT ''?'', Count(*) as NumberOfRows FROM ?'

    Rebuild all indexes of all tables in a database
    
    EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="print '?' DBCC DBREINDEX ('?', ' ', 80)"
GO
```

Note: DBCC DBREINDEX has been deprecated in SQL 2005. Microsoft says "This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature. Use ALTER INDEX instead."

```
Disable all constraints of all tables in a database


USE YOURDBNAME

EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL"



Disable all Triggers of all tables in a database


USE YOURDBNAME

EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? DISABLE TRIGGER ALL'



Delete all data from all tables in your database


-- disable referential integrity

EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'

GO

 

EXEC sp_MSForEachTable '

 IF OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id(''?''), ''TableHasForeignRef'') = 1

  DELETE FROM ?

 else

  TRUNCATE TABLE ?

'

GO

 

-- enable referential integrity again

EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'

GO



To RESEED all table to 0, use this script
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable '
IF OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id(''?''), ''TableHasIdentity'') = 1
DBCC CHECKIDENT (''?'', RESEED, 0)
GO
```

guys share your knowledge at one place so lots of developers gain bani fits from this.

Comment: Since they're undocumented, there's a risk using them - they might be missing or changed in a next version of SQL Server. Just be aware of that possibility (and don't complain about that, if you do use undocumented stuff!).

Comment: You'll find a lot of related information in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121243/hidden-features-of-sql-server

Comment: You guys closing this post is a whole lot like censorship in the extreme. Other than it not being a question, why would you shut down a post that offered an answer without there being a question?  Stop being so bloody Draconian. ;-)

Comment: @JeffModen Agreed. It would have been easy enough to restructure this to be a simple question with the rest of the text added to a community wiki answer.