# What is the use of this table: 'Master.dbo.spt_Values'?

Tags: sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the purpose of system table table master..spt_values   and what are the meanings of its values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273723/what-is-the-purpose-of-system-table-table-master-spt-values-and-what-are-the-m)

Could anyone tell me what is the use of this table in the SQL Server database?

Comment: Psst.... not reason to shout ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's a lookup table for SQL Server configuration options.