# in sql2005 what is master.dbo.spt_values and how do you use it?

Tags: sql-server-2005

as startted int he title:
in sql2005 what is master.dbo.spt_values and how do you use it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of system table table master..spt_values   and what are the meanings of its values? ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273723/what-is-the-purpose-of-system-table-table-master-spt-values-and-what-are-the-m)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've no idea what its actual purpose is but you will often see it pressed into service as a handy adhoc numbers table with numbers between 0-2047.

```
select number from master..spt_values where type='P'
```

Some examples of where this would be useful are listed here: [Why should I consider using an auxiliary numbers table](http://web.archive.org/web/20150411042510/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-numbers-table.html)?

For your own code you are much better off creating your own permanent indexed numbers table though.