# Help with a complex join query

Tags: sql-server-2000

Keep in mind I am using SQL 2000

I have two tables.

`tblAutoPolicyList` contains a field called `PolicyIDList`.

`tblLossClaims` contains two fields called `LossPolicyID` & `PolicyReview`.

I am writing a stored proc that will get the distinct `PolicyID` from `PolicyIDList` field, and loop through `LossPolicyID` field (if match is found, set `PolicyReview` to 'Y').

Sample table layout:

```
PolicyIDList        LossPolicyID 
9651XVB19       5021WWA85, 4421WWA20, 3314WWA31, 1121WAW11, 2221WLL99       Y
5021WWA85       3326WAC35, 1221AXA10, 9863AAA44, 5541RTY33, 9651XVB19       Y
0151ZVB19       4004WMN63, 1001WGA42, 8587ABA56, 8541RWW12, 9329KKB08       N
```

How would I go about writing the stored proc (looking for logic more than syntax)?

Keep in mind I am using SQL 2000.

Comment: So you are writing a stored procedure to de-normalise your data model?

Comment: Is the PolicyIDList field a single field with a delimited list of Policy IDs? (AAAA BBBB CCCC or AAAA,BBBB,CCCC) ?

Comment: PolicyIDList is a field that contains only one ID per row; LossPolicyID is a field with comma seperated values;

Comment: It's ironical how a single item column is named 'ItemList' while at the same time a list column is essentially simply 'Item'. :) Sorry if it's a thousandth time you hear that. Actually I'd like some details about these IDs and about `LossPolicyID` arrangement. Is the length of a single item fixed? Is the list format in `LossPolicyID` fixed (item, comma, space, item, comma, space...) Is the item quantity in a single `LossPolicyID` value fixed (it's always 5 in your example)? Or is there some maximum quantity per row?

Comment: length of the single item is fixed; it is comma delimited (I use trim to take off the space); quantity can be 1 policyID or 10 or 15; Its a crazy setup, but I do what I am told to do :-)

Answer (score 2):

Select LossPolicyID, * from tableName where charindex('PolicyID',LossPolicyID,1)>0

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the idea is this:

1. 'Unroll' `tblLossClaims` and return two columns: a `tblLossClaims` key (you didn't mention any, so I guess it's going to be `LossPolicyID`) and `Item` = a single item from `LossPolicyID`.
2. Find matches of `unrolled.Item` in `tblAutoPolicyList.PolicyIDList`.
3. Find matches of distinct `matched.LossPolicyID` in `tblLossClaims.LossPolicyID`.
4. Update `tblLossClaims.PolicyReview` accordingly.

The main UPDATE can look like this:

```
UPDATE claims
   SET PolicyReview = 'Y'
  FROM tblLossClaims claims
  JOIN (
       SELECT DISTINCT unrolled.LossPolicyID
         FROM (
              SELECT LossPolicyID, Item = itemof(LossPolicyID)
                FROM unrolling_join
              ) unrolled
         JOIN tblAutoPolicyList
           ON unrolled.ID = tblAutoPolicyList.PolicyIDList
       ) matched
    ON matched.LossPolicyID = claims.LossPolicyID
```

You can take advantage of the fixed item width and the fixed list format and thus easily split `LossPolicyID` without a UDF. I can see this done with the help of a number table and `SUBSTRING()`. `unrolling_join` in the above query is actually `tblLossClaims` joined with the number table.

Here's the definition of `unrolled` 'zoomed in':

```
...
(
SELECT LossPolicyID,
       Item = SUBSTRING(LossPolicyID,
                        (v.number - 1) * @ItemLength + 1,
                        @ItemLength)
  FROM tblLossClaims c
  JOIN master..spt_values v ON v.type = 'P'
   AND v.number BETWEEN 1 AND (LEN(c.LossPolicyID) + 2) / (@ItemLength + 2)
) unrolled
...
```

[`master..spt_values`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273723/what-is-the-purpose-of-system-table-table-master-spt-values-and-what-are-the-m) is a system table that is used here as the number table. Filter `v.type = 'P'` gives us a rowset with number values from 0 to 2047, which is narrowed down to the list of numbers from 1 to the number of items in `LossPolicyID`. Eventually `v.number` serves as an array index and is used to cut out single items.

@ItemLength is of course simply `LEN(tblAutoPolicyList.PolicyIDList)`. I would probably also declared `@ItemLength2 = @ItemLength + 2` so it wasn't calculated every time when applying the filter.

Basically, that's it, if I haven't missed anything.

Answer (score 0):

If the PolicyIDList field is a delimited list, you have to first separate the individual policy IDs and create a temporary table with all of the results. Next up, use an update query on the tblLossClaims with 'where exists (select * from #temptable tt where tt.PolicyID = LossPolicyID).

Depending on the size of the table/data, you might wish to add an index to your temporary table.

Comment: Also, check out http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=50648 for help on creating a split function