# SQL: problem word count with len()

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to count words of text that is written in a column of table. Therefor I am using the following query.

```
SELECT LEN(ExtractedText) - 
LEN(REPLACE(ExtractedText, ' ', '')) + 1 from EDDSDBO.Document where ID='100'.
```

I receive a wrong result that is much to high. 
On the other hand, if I copy the text directly into the statement then it works, i.e.

```
SELECT LEN('blablabla text') - LEN(REPLACE('blablabla text', ' ', '')) + 1.
```

Now the datatype is `nvarchar(max)` since the text is very long. I have already tried to convert the column into `text` or `ntext` and to apply `datalength()` instead of `len()`. Nevertheless I obtain the same result that it does work as a string but does not work from a table.

Comment: Do a `SELECT ExtractedText FROM EDDSDBO.Document WHERE ID='100'` make sure the string is what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 2):

You're counting spaces not words. That will typically yield an approximate answer.

e.g.

```
'  this     string    will    give an    incorrect      result   '
```

Try this approach: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/functions/count-words.aspx

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[WordCount] ( @InputString VARCHAR(4000) ) 
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Index          INT
DECLARE @Char           CHAR(1)
DECLARE @PrevChar       CHAR(1)
DECLARE @WordCount      INT

SET @Index = 1
SET @WordCount = 0

WHILE @Index <= LEN(@InputString)
BEGIN
    SET @Char     = SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index, 1)
    SET @PrevChar = CASE WHEN @Index = 1 THEN ' '
                         ELSE SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index - 1, 1)
                    END

    IF @PrevChar = ' ' AND @Char != ' '
        SET @WordCount = @WordCount + 1

    SET @Index = @Index + 1
END

RETURN @WordCount

END
GO
```

usage

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(4000)
SET @String = 'Health Insurance is an insurance against expenses incurred through illness of the insured.'

SELECT [dbo].[WordCount] ( @String )
```

Answer (score 1):

Leading spaces, trailing spaces, two or more spaces between the neighbouring words – these are the likely causes of the wrong results you are getting.

The functions `LTRIM()` and `RTRIM()` can help you eliminate the first two issues. As for the third one, you can use `REPLACE(ExtractedText, '  ', ' ')` to replace double spaces with single ones, but I'm not sure if you do not have triple ones (in which case you'd need to repeat the replacing).

---

**UPDATE**

Here's a UDF that uses [CTEs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) and [ranking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) to eliminate extra spaces and then counts the remaining ones to return the quantity as the number of words:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnCountWords (@Str varchar(max))
RETURNS int
AS BEGIN
  DECLARE @xml xml, @res int;
  SET @Str = RTRIM(LTRIM(@Str));
  WITH split AS (
    SELECT
      idx = number,
      chr = SUBSTRING(@Str, number, 1)
    FROM master..spt_values
    WHERE type = 'P'
      AND number BETWEEN 1 AND LEN(@Str)
  ),
  ranked AS (
    SELECT
      idx,
      chr,
        rnk = idx - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY chr ORDER BY idx)
      FROM split
  )
  SELECT @res = COUNT(DISTINCT rnk) + 1
  FROM ranked
  WHERE chr = ' ';
  RETURN @res;
END
```

With this function your query will be simply like this:

```
SELECT fnCountWords(ExtractedText)
FROM EDDSDBO.Document
WHERE ID='100'
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

The function uses one of the system tables, [`master..spt_values`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273723/what-is-the-purpose-of-system-table-table-master-spt-values-and-what-are-the-mea), as a tally table. The particular subset used contains only values from 0 to 2047. This means the function will not work correctly for inputs longer than 2047 characters (after trimming both leading and trailing spaces), as @t-clausen.dk has correctly noted in his comment. Therefore, a custom [tally table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/) should be used if longer input strings are possible.

Comment: nvarchar(max) is very long, you could run into problems when there are more than 2047 words

Comment: Thanks, I added the necessary note.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the spaces with something that never occur in your text like ' $!' or pick another value.
then replace all '$! ' and '$!' with nothing this way you never have more than 1 space after a word. Then use your current script. I have defined a word as a space followed by a non-space.

This is an example

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(COL1 NVARCHAR(2000), ID INT)

INSERT @T VALUES('A B  C   D', 100)

SELECT LEN(C) - LEN(REPLACE(C,' ', '')) COUNT FROM (
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(' ' + COL1, ' ', ' $!'), '$! ',''), '$!', '') C
FROM @T ) A
```

Here is a recursive solution

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(COL1 NVARCHAR(2000), ID INT)

INSERT @T VALUES('A B  C   D', 100)
INSERT @T VALUES('have a nice day with 7 words', 100)

;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT 1 words, col1 c, col1 FROM @t WHERE id = 100
UNION ALL
SELECT words +1, right(c, len(c) - patindex('% [^ ]%', c)), col1 FROM cte
WHERE patindex('% [^ ]%', c) > 0
)
SELECT words, col1 FROM cte WHERE patindex('% [^ ]%', c) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the column using the `varchar` data type, like:

```
create table emp(ename varchar(22));

insert into emp values('amit');

select ename,len(ename) from emp;
```

> output : 4

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question, as I understand it, the OP is interested in counting words