# stored procedure to update table date range sql

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-insert

I have created a stored procedure to insert records into a table for holidays. At the moment I can only get it to insert a single date. What i would like to do is be able to use a between to enter a full week or month ect.

My stored procedure is :

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[usp_UpdateVacationTable&Alert]
(
    @VacationDate DATETIME,
    @VacationType NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @VacationTypeID INT,
    @StaffCode NVARCHAR(4),
    @StaffName NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Notes NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @FTE FLOAT,
    @CreatedBy NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @CreatedDate DATETIME
)
as
begin

    insert tblVacationRecords
    (
       VacationDate
      , VacationType
      , VacationTypeID
      , StaffCode
      , StaffName
      , Notes
      , FTE
      , CreatedBy
      , CreatedDate
    )
    values
    (
            @VacationDate,
            @VacationType,
            @VacationTypeID,
            @StaffCode,
            @StaffName,
            @Notes,
            @FTE,  
            @CreatedBy,
            @CreatedDate
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to use BETWEEN in your case. But I would suggest you to look into table valued parameters: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/passing-table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server-2008/

Comment: Could I include a datediff in the proc to calculate the days booked off if I add a startdate and enddate?

Comment: In stored procedure you basically can do anything t-sql. What I offer is that you prepare the range of data in your application, put it into table variable, and then pass it to stored proc.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: [How to generate a range of dates in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141507/how-to-generate-a-range-of-dates-in-sql-server) and this [You require a numbers table](http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/) This is easier & more  efficient with a numbers table if you are running this often. Otherwise you can use the system tables like these examples to get a range you can join against