# sql begin end week of year

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I do cant get the begin and end week between two dates in Sql Server? for example:

```
    begin       end
    2016-04-25  2016-05-01
    2016-05-02  2016-05-08
    2016-05-09  2016-05-15
    2016-05-16  2016-05-22
    2016-05-23  2016-05-29
    2016-05-30  2016-06-05
...
```

Regards!

Comment: Which `DBMS` you are using. Did you try anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
DECLARE @d1 DATE = '2016-04-20' , @d2 DATE = '2016-06-07'
, @mon1 DATE
;WITH 
sunA AS (
  SELECT k=1, dt = @d1, dn = datename(dw,@d1)
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT k=k+1, dt = DATEADD(d,1,dt), dn = datename(dw,DATEADD(d,1,dt))
  FROM sunA 
  WHERE k<7
) 
  SELECT TOP 1 @mon1 = dt 
  FROM sunA
  WHERE dn = 'Monday'
  ORDER BY k

DECLARE @weeks TABLE(d1 DATE, d2 DATE)
WHILE @mon1 >= @d1 AND DATEADD(d, 6, @mon1) <= @d2
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO @weeks SELECT @mon1, DATEADD(d, 6, @mon1)
  SET @mon1 = DATEADD(d, 7, @mon1)
END

SELECT * FROM @weeks

-- OUTPUT
d1          d2
2016-04-25  2016-05-01
2016-05-02  2016-05-08
2016-05-09  2016-05-15
2016-05-16  2016-05-22
2016-05-23  2016-05-29
2016-05-30  2016-06-05
```

Comment: hello @leoinfo is perfect, this is the function that I needed, thank you very much, wow!!!

Comment: @NelsonCalderon - I don't think `CTE` works in `SQL Server 2005`

Comment: @Prdp - CTE was introduced with SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 0):

SQL has the `DATEDIFF(datepart,startdate,enddate)` function for this purpose.

Example:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,'2014-06-05','2014-08-05') AS DiffDate
```

results in

```
61
```

Learn more about `DATEFIFF` [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp)

Comment: thx, I dont need datediff, I need get 'dates' for begin of week and end, day begin monday for example.

Comment: How do you mean that? Which date "for begin of week"? @NelsonCalderon

Answer (score 0):

use DATEDIFF() function in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

You need a date table to do this

```
Declare @start_date datetime = '2016-04-25'
        @end_date datetime = '2016-06-05'

SELECT Min(dt) AS week_start, 
       Max(dt) AS week_end 
FROM   dates_table 
WHERE  date_col > @start_date 
       AND date_col < @end_date 
GROUP  BY Datepart(week, dt), 
          Year(dt) 
ORDER  BY Datepart(week, dt), 
          Year(dt)
```

To create a date table and populate dates, Here is few question about generating dates between range of dates

1. [How to generate a range of dates in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141507/how-to-generate-a-range-of-dates-in-sql-server)
2. [Generate Dates between date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824831/generate-dates-between-date-ranges)