# SQL: Daily report for with user counts

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the 30 days report of **users**, that will return **date** and **total count of users** as count created on that date and i did it with this query

```
 Select count(*)  As [Count] ,  
        (SELECT CONVERT(date, AddDate)) As [Date] 
 from Users 
 WHERE AddDate  >= (SELECT DateAdd(month, -1, Convert(date, GetDate()))) 
 Group By CONVERT(date, AddDate)
```

it give me only those dates on which any user is created, but i want to show all **30 days** either if it has **count** **0**.

Same Case i want to do with monthly report.
i am getting months in which users are created , now i want to change it to get **last 12 months** from this month and their **total users count**. For this i am using this query

```
 Select count(*)  As [Count] ,
        (Select DATEPART( month , DateAdd( month , DATEPART(mm,AddDate) , -1 ) )) as Month
 from Users 
 WHERE AddDate  >= (SELECT DateAdd(YEAR, -1, Convert(date, GetDate())))
 Group By DATEPART(mm,AddDate)
```

Comment: You need a `Calendar table` and `Left Join`

Answer (score 5):

Using a Calendar CTE:

```
With NumberSequence ( Number ) as
(
    Select 1 as Number
    union all
    Select Number + 1
    from NumberSequence
    where Number <= 30
)
, CalendarCTE as
(
    select cast(dateadd(dd, -30 + Number,getdate()) as Date) as CalDate
    from Numbersequence
)

select CalDate, count(U1.*) as CountUsers
from CalendarCTE
left join Users U1
on CalDate = convert(date, U1.AddDate)
group by CalDate
```

Comment: cast the column 'CalDate' to Date,other wise this will return the time part also.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in comment, You need a `Calendar table` and `Left Join`

```
SELECT Count(u.adddate) AS [Count], 
       c.dates  AS [Date] 
FROM   calendar_table C 
       LEFT JOIN users U 
              ON c.dates = CONVERT(DATE, adddate) 
WHERE  c.dates >= Dateadd(month, -1, CONVERT(DATE, Getdate())) 
GROUP  BY c.dates
```

To generate/create a calendar table or dates check out the below questions

[How to generate a range of dates in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141507/how-to-generate-a-range-of-dates-in-sql-server)

[Generate Dates between date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824831/generate-dates-between-date-ranges)

[How to create a Calender table for 100 years in Sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635594/how-to-create-a-calender-table-for-100-years-in-sql)

Comment: Calendar table is overkill. Why not a 30 day calendar CTE?

Comment: @JohnHC - The idea is sort of calendar table not exactly calendar table

Answer (score 2):

**Try this script :**

```
WITH CTEDates
AS
(
  SELECT CAST(GetDate() as date) AS [date]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, [date])
  FROM CTEDates
  WHERE DAY([date]) <= 30
)
Select count(*)  As [Count] ,CONVERT(date, AddDate) As [Date] 
from CTEDates 
LEFT JOIN Users ON CTEDates.date=CONVERT(date, AddDate)
WHERE AddDate  >= DateAdd(month, -1, GetDate())
Group By CONVERT(date, AddDate)
```

Comment: The CTE won't work. It's the increment that needs to be limited, not the day of the date. Otherwise, Oct 31st won't appear...

Comment: Well, good to know about this but this will give Oct 31s,I have tested it before posting the Ans :)

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @StartDate Datetime
DECLARE @EndDate Datetime

CREATE TABLE #tMyCalanderDate (dtDate Datetime Primary key)

SELECT @StartDate = '01-Sep-2016'
SELECT @EndDate  =  '30-Sep-2016'

WHILE @StartDate <= @EndDate
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #tMyCalanderDate (dtDate)
    SELECT @StartDate 

    SELECT @StartDate = DATEADD(day,1,@StartDate)

END

SELECT count(A.UserID)  As [Count] , B.dtDate As [Date] 
FROM Users AS A
RIGHT JOIN #tMyCalanderDate AS B ON CONVERT(date, A.AddDate) = CONVERT(date, B.dtDate)  
WHERE CONVERT(date, A.AddDate) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
Group By CONVERT(date, B.dtDate)
```

Comment: Azure Synapse Analytics (data warehouse) does not support recursion in a CTE so variations on this method to create the temp table can be used instead of the other suggestions here.

Comment: However, here's a link to a faster method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7825036/1803823

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CTE to get a thirty day calendar. Then left join your Users table to it.

```
DECLARE @CurrentTime DATETIME = GETDATE()
;WITH CTE AS
    (
      SELECT CONVERT(DATE, @CurrentTime) AS [Date]

      UNION ALL

      SELECT  DATEADD(dd, -1, Date)
      FROM    CTE
      WHERE   DATEADD(dd, 29, Date) > @CurrentTime
    )
SELECT COUNT(U.AddDate) AS [Count]
, CTE.[Date] AS [Date]
FROM CTE
LEFT JOIN users U
ON CTE.Date = CONVERT(Date, AddDate)
GROUP BY CTE.Date
```

You can use a similar CTE to get the twelve month calendar and use the same joins to get the count.

HTH.