# Fill date gaps in SQL query with zeros

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following structure (which came from some joins across tables,etc) which will be used to produce a chart.

Some IDs do not have data for all the dates, which result in some dashed lines in the chart.

The question is, how can I add the missing dates for each ID and fill their data cell with zeros?

[image]

As script:

```
(67, '2016-09-28 00:00:00.000',1),
(178, '2016-09-28 00:00:00.000',6),
(42, '2016-09-25 00:00:00.000',1),
(66, '2016-09-25 00:00:00.000',122),
(67, '2016-09-25 00:00:00.000',2),
(10, '2016-09-24 00:00:00.000',5),
(13, '2016-09-24 00:00:00.000',4),
(66, '2016-09-24 00:00:00.000',198),
(67, '2016-09-24 00:00:00.000',15),
(178, '2016-09-24 00:00:00.000',4),
(10, '2016-09-23 00:00:00.000',1),
(13, '2016-09-23 00:00:00.000',2),
(42, '2016-09-23 00:00:00.000',4),
(66, '2016-09-23 00:00:00.000',208),
(67, '2016-09-23 00:00:00.000',15)
```

Comment: I think you will need to use a calendar table of some sort.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL: Daily report for with user counts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849213/sql-daily-report-for-with-user-counts)

Comment: @JohnHC I couldn't visualise the data structure so can't tell for sure if this is a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more way with calendar table and CROSS JOIN:

```
;WITH YourQueryOutput AS (
--put your select statement here
), calendar AS (
SELECT  CAST(MIN(RoundedTime) as datetime) as d,
        MAX(RoundedTime) as e
FROM YourQueryOutput
UNION ALL
SELECT  DATEADD(day,1,d),
        e
FROM calendar
WHERE d < e
)

SELECT  t.ID,
        c.d,
        COALESCE(t1.[data],0) as [data]
FROM calendar c
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ID
    FROM YourQueryOutput
    ) t
LEFT JOIN YourQueryOutput t1
    ON t.ID = t1.ID and t1.RoundedTime = c.d
ORDER BY t.ID, c.d
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Output for sample you provided

```
ID  d                       data
10  2016-09-23 00:00:00.000 1
10  2016-09-24 00:00:00.000 5
10  2016-09-25 00:00:00.000 0
10  2016-09-26 00:00:00.000 0
10  2016-09-27 00:00:00.000 0
10  2016-09-28 00:00:00.000 0
...
178 2016-09-23 00:00:00.000 0
178 2016-09-24 00:00:00.000 4
178 2016-09-25 00:00:00.000 0
178 2016-09-26 00:00:00.000 0
178 2016-09-27 00:00:00.000 0
178 2016-09-28 00:00:00.000 6
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method:

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
select i.id, rt.roundedtime, coalesce(data, 0) as data
from (select distinct id from t) i cross join
     (select distinct roundedtime rt from t) rt left join
     t
     on t.id = i.id and t.roundedtime = rt.roundedtime;
```

In other words, create the list of dates and `id`s using a `cross join`.  Then use a `left join` to bring in your data.

This query uses `select distinct` on your original data to get the lists of dates and ids.  There may be more efficient ways to get each of these lists.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. the problem is that not all dates are listed so they don't show up in your query

Answer (score 0):

You can check **ISNULL(YourDataColumn,0)** in SELECT statement where you used join.

**Example:**

```
SELECT
    Q.QuestionId,
    Q.SenderType,
    ISNULL(Q.Data,0) AS Data
FROM @tblQuestion Q
LEFT JOIN @tblTeacher T ON Q.SenderId=T.Id AND Q.SENDERTYPE='TEACHER'
LEFT JOIN @tblInstitute I ON Q.SenderId=I.Id AND Q.SENDERTYPE='INSTITUTE'
```

IN above Select Statement `Data column return 0` if no data available after join

Comment: As I understand there are some IDs which don't get in that query, and OP needs to show them with missing dates and zeros.

Comment: AS per i understand in output table no data in against some date so chart not render proper, so there should be some data if chart accept int then 0 else other value as per data type

Comment: @gofr1: That's right, there are gaps in both IDs and RoundedTime in that query, so an ISNULL will not do much here