# How to add date column to the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to add date field column to the current table.

I need to add Jan1 to Dec31 of 2018 to the column named date.

I tried with following query,

```
 Insert into [dbo].[Calendar]  ([Date])
 Values
 Getdate()
```

It throws syntax error near getdate().

Please help me with the query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How to generate a range of dates in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141507/how-to-generate-a-range-of-dates-in-sql-server).

Comment: That link is explaining about particular dates, how to simple add the dates without using variables?

Comment: Your comment makes no sense.  This is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 2):

You can try below using recursive cte

```
DECLARE @startDt date='2018-01-01'
DECLARE @endtDt date='2018-12-31'    

;WITH GetDates As  
(  
SELECT 1 AS [COUNTER], @startDt as [Date]
UNION ALL  
SELECT [COUNTER] + 1, DATEADD(DAY,1,[Date])  
FROM GetDates  
WHERE [Date] < @endtDt   
)  
SELECT [DATE] FROM GetDates 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: your script has thrown conversion issues

Answer (score 0):

wrap getdate() inside braces.

```
Insert into [dbo].[Calendar]  ([Date])
 Values
 (Getdate())
```

And for adding Jan1 to Dec31 of 2018 use below code

```
declare @startDt date='2018-01-01'
declare @endtDt date='2018-12-31'
while (@startDt<=@endtDt)
begin
    Insert into [dbo].[Calendar]  ([Date]) Values (@startDt)
    set @startDt=dateadd(dd,1,@startDt)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but this command adds only to 1 row, but how to add all 365 days?

Comment: Although this is correct, doing a loop isn't the best way, performance-wise.

Answer (score 0):

Try this without using Recursive Cte

```
DECLARE @startDt date='2018-01-01'
DECLARE @endtDt date='2018-12-31'

SELECT DATEADD(DAY,Number,@startDt) AS RecurringDates
FROM Master.dbo.spt_values
WHERE [type] ='P'
AND DATEADD(DAY,Number,@startDt) BETWEEN @startDt AND @endtDt
ORDER BY 1
```