# Date range to row in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I have a table in postgres like this:

| id | open_date | close_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2006-08-04 | 2019-12-31 |

There exist 4897 days between them. I need to turn the date range to date to have one record per day. For example:

| id | open_date | close_date | valid_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2006-08-04 | 2019-12-31 | 2006-08-04 |
| 5 | 2006-08-04 | 2019-12-31 | 2006-08-05 |
| 5 | 2006-08-04 | 2019-12-31 | 2006-08-06 |
| ... | .......... | .......... | .......... |
| 5 | 2006-08-04 | 2019-12-31 | 2019-12-31 |

I tried the query provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11141693/10159346) like this:

```
SELECT
    id,
    open_date,
    close_date,
    open_date + seq.seqnum * interval '1 day' AS valid_date,
  FROM
    TAB1
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            row_number() over () AS seqnum
        FROM
            TAB1) seq ON seqnum <= (close_date - open_date)
         )
```

The TAB1 contains 600 rows. After running this query it produce correct records but only max 600 records for each id. This means for this date range only till 2008-06-08

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Postgres, you would use `generate_series()`:

```
select t1.*, gs.valid_date
from tab1 t1 cross join lateral
     generate_series(t1.open_date, t1.close_date, interval '1 day') as gs(valid_date);
```