# Looping in SELECT statement in ms sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server 2008 Generate a Series of date times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149271/sql-server-2008-generate-a-series-of-date-times)

I have to Loop through a startDate and endDate

The SELECT statement should produce result as..

Expected Output :

```
------------
Date
------------
09/01/2012 -> startDate
09/02/2012
09/03/2012
.
.
.
.
09/30/2012 -> endDate
```

i tried

```
declare @startDate datetime , @endDate endDate
set @startDate='09/01/2012'
set @endDate='09/30/2012'

while DATEDIFF(@startDate,@endDate)!=-1
begin
select @startDate as Date
set @startDate = DATEADD(day,2,@startDate)
end
```

But its not working out..

it generates 30 outputs..

i want the dates in a single output as in the expected output..

where am i going wrong here guys ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That will give you a resultset for each loop iteration as you `select` per iteration.

If you want a single resultset insert into a temp table/variable per iteration then select from it or

```
;with T(day) as
(
    select @startDate as day
        union all
    select day + 1
        from T
        where day < @endDate
)
select day as [Date] from T
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a `WHILE` loop:

```
declare @startDate datetime , @endDate datetime
set @startDate='09/01/2012'
set @endDate='09/30/2012'

create table #temp (startDate datetime)   

while @startDate <= @endDate
    begin
        insert into #temp
        select @startDate as Date
        set @startDate = DATEADD(day,1,@startDate)
    end

select *
from #temp

drop table #temp
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/93b55/1)

Comment: thanks and sqlfiddle in nice..

Answer (score 0):

You could create a temp table for the values and select from that in the end, after the iteration.

```
declare @temp table (TheDate date)

declare @startDate datetime , @endDate datetime
set @startDate='09/01/2012'
set @endDate='09/30/2012'

while DATEDIFF(day, @startDate, @endDate)!=-1
begin
insert into @temp (thedate) values (@startDate)
set @startDate = DATEADD(day,2,@startDate)
end
select * from @temp
```

edit: The cte Alex suggest is imo a much cleaner way to do it, and more of a sql way to do it, without using loops or cursors.