# How can I find how many Week Numbers are in a given interval of time in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a bit stuck here, I want to find all the week numbers in a given interval of time and I can't really figure it out

For example , instead of 
 `- > datepart(week,dateadd(day,-1,@oneSingleDate))` (monday is the first day of the week)   ,

I need something like

```
- > datepart(week,@startDate,@endDate)
```

Given the interval `'2019-01-04'-'2019-01-28'` the output needs to be :

WeekNo : `1,2,3,4,5` .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2008 Generate a Series of date times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149271/sql-server-2008-generate-a-series-of-date-times)

Comment: Join against a calendar table with a between and retrieve the week numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Stuff and 'For Xml Path' work in Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211506/how-stuff-and-for-xml-path-work-in-sql-server)

Comment: Simply combine both duplicated questions/answer for a query which will give you the correct resultset, in SQL Server 2017 you can use [STRING_AGG()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead of `STUFF`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've used a recursive CTE to generate all the dates in the range, then I've selected the DISTINCT week numbers from them using DATEPART.  Then I've concatenated then into your comma-separated string into a variable called @OUT

```
DECLARE @startDate as date = '20190104';
DECLARE @endDate as date = '2019-01-28';

DECLARE @OUT as nvarchar(max);

WITH CTE AS (SELECT @startDate As X
             UNION ALL
             SELECT DATEADD(y, 1, X) X FROM CTE where x < @endDate),
    CTE2 AS (SELECT DISTINCT datepart(wk, X) wk from cte)
    select @out = coalesce(@out + ', ', '') + cast(wk as nvarchar(4))  from cte2
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);

    select @out;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:
using :
 - [CTE][1] common Table expression
 - [Sql recursion union all][2]
 - [Concatenation of multiple rows into one line][3]

```
declare @startDate as date ;
declare @endDate as date ;
set @startDate='2019-01-04'; 
set @endDate='2019-01-28' ;
DECLARE @weeks VARCHAR(8000) ;
with cte as (select @startDate as mydate,datepart(week,@startDate) w
union all select
dateadd(day,1,mydate),datepart(week,dateadd(day,1,mydate))  from cte
where mydate < @endDate) , cte2 as (select distinct(w) from cte)
select @weeks=COALESCE(@weeks + ', ', '') +cast(w as varchar(2)) from
cte2 OPTION (MAXRECURSION 360) select @weeks [Result]
```