# Merge continuous rows with Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `slots` table like this :

```
   Column   |            Type             |
------------+-----------------------------+
 id         | integer                     |
 begin_at   | timestamp without time zone |
 end_at     | timestamp without time zone |
 user_id    | integer                     |
```

and I like to select merged rows for continuous time. Let's say I have (simplified) data like :

```
(1, 5:15, 5:30, 1)
(2, 5:15, 5:30, 2)
(3, 5:30, 5:45, 2)
(4, 5:45, 6:00, 2)
(5, 8:15, 8:30, 2)
(6, 8:30, 8:45, 2)
```

I would like to know if it's possible to select rows formatted like :

```
(5:15, 5:30, 1)
(5:15, 6:00, 2) // <======= rows id 2,3 and 4 merged
(8:15, 8:45, 2) // <======= rows id 5 and 6 merged
```

**EDIT:**
Here's the [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1b58d/1%20SQLfiddle)

I'm using Postgresql, version 9.3!

Thank you!

Comment: Can you sqlfiddle your data?

Comment: Similar question for SQL Server http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520556/query-to-merge-continuous-temporal-records

Comment: Use a recursive query, start at front-unjoinable begin-stubs. Extend by joining following segment. Final select only the longest paths.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is one method for solving this problem.  Create a flag that determines if a one record does *not* overlap with the previous one.  This is the start of a group.  Then take the cumulative sum of this flag and use that for grouping:

```
select user_id, min(begin_at) as begin_at, max(end_at) as end_at
from (select s.*, sum(startflag) over (partition by user_id order by begin_at) as grp
      from (select s.*,
                   (case when lag(end_at) over (partition by user_id order by begin_at) >= begin_at
                         then 0 else 1
                    end) as startflag
            from slots s
           ) s
     ) s
group by user_id, grp;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1b58d/12) is a SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Gordon Linoff already provided the answer (I upvoted).

I've used the same approach, but wanted to deal with [`tsrange` type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/rangetypes.html).
So I came up with [this construct](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1b58d/23):

```sql
SELECT min(id) b_id, min(begin_at) b_at, max(end_at) e_at, grp, user_id
  FROM (
    SELECT t.*, sum(g) OVER (ORDER BY id) grp
      FROM (
        SELECT s.*, (NOT r -|- lag(r,1,r)
                     OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY id))::int g
          FROM (SELECT id,begin_at,end_at,user_id,
                       tsrange(begin_at,end_at,'[)') r FROM slots) s
      ) t
  ) u
 GROUP BY grp, user_id
 ORDER BY grp;
```

Unfortunately, on the top level one has to use `min(begin_at)` and `max(end_at)`, as there're no aggregate functions for the range-based union operator `+`.

I create ranges with exclusive upper bounds, this allows me to use [“is adjacent to” (`-|-`) operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-range.html). I compare current `tsrange` with the one on the previous row, defaulting to the current one in case there's no previous. Then I negate the comparison and cast to `integer`, which gives me `1` in cases when new group starts.