# SQL how to convert row with date range to many rows with each date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

If I have a table that looks like this

```
begin date      end date        data
 2013-01-01     2013-01-04       7
 2013-01-05     2013-01-06       9
```

How can I make it be returned like this...

```
    date         data
 2013-01-01       7
 2013-01-02       7
 2013-01-03       7
 2013-01-04       7
 2013-01-05       9
 2013-01-06       9
```

One thing I was thinking of doing is to have another table that just has all the dates and then join the table with just dates to the above table using `date>=begin date` and `date<=end date` but that seems a little clunky to have to maintain that extra table with nothing but repetitive dates.

In some instances I don't have a data range but just an `as of` date which basically looks like my first example but with no `end date`.  The `end date` is implied by the next row's 'as of' date (ie end date should be the next row's `as of` -1).  I had a "solution" for this that uses the row_number() function to get the next value but I suspect that methodology, which the way I'm doing it has a bunch of nested self joins, contributes to very long query times.

Comment: You're reinterpreting data, for which you shouldn't use SQL. On the business logic end this is 2~3 lines of code extra without burdening the database with something it was never meant to be able to do easily.

Comment: @Niels Which part are you saying shouldn't happen on the SQL server?  Are you saying I should store my data in the format that I want it to be displayed or that I should use another process besides the SQL server to generate the output in the format that I want?

Comment: No, you should store data in the DB in a normalized correct indexable fashion, as you are doing now. Presentation is not a DB's task, so do that in the invoking code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using some sample data...

```
create table data (begindate datetime, enddate datetime, data int);
insert data select 
 '20130101', '20130104', 7 union all select
 '20130105', '20130106', 9;
```

**The Query**: (Note: if you already have a numbers/tally table - use it)

```
select dateadd(d,v.number,d.begindate) adate, data
  from data d
  join master..spt_values v on v.type='P'
       and v.number between 0 and datediff(d, begindate, enddate)
order by adate;
```

**Results**:

```
|                       COLUMN_0 | DATA |
-----------------------------------------
| January, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 |    7 |
| January, 02 2013 00:00:00+0000 |    7 |
| January, 03 2013 00:00:00+0000 |    7 |
| January, 04 2013 00:00:00+0000 |    7 |
| January, 05 2013 00:00:00+0000 |    9 |
| January, 06 2013 00:00:00+0000 |    9 |
```

---

Alternatively you can generate a number table on the fly (0-99) or as many numbers as you need

```
;WITH Numbers(number) AS (
  select top(100) row_number() over (order by (select 0))-1
  from sys.columns a
  cross join sys.columns b
  cross join sys.columns c
  cross join sys.columns d
  )
select dateadd(d,v.number,d.begindate) adate, data
  from data d
  join Numbers v on v.number between 0 and datediff(d, begindate, enddate)
order by adate;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/954e2/1)

Comment: Despite admittedly being a rather brilliant solution to the problem, the `spt_values` table is an undocumented feature of SQL Server, and as such not guaranted to keep working, or never change. Ref [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273723/what-is-the-purpose-of-system-table-table-master-spt-values-and-what-are-the-me)

Comment: I don't believe the table will ever go away, but I have added an alternative. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: So glad I found this question & answer.  This was part of a test in a job interview.  The goal made sense to me, but the solution is tricky.  Glad I found your simple and perfect solution!

Comment: The fiddle is failing, does this still work in 2019?

Comment: @Notflip sqlfiddle had no working sql2014 hosts, switched link to use sql2017

Answer (score 3):

You can use recursive CTE to get all the dates between two dates. Another CTE is to get ROW_NUMBERs to help you with those missing EndDates.

```
DECLARE @startDate DATE
DECLARE @endDate DATE

SELECT @startDate = MIN(begindate) FROM Table1
SELECT @endDate = MAX(enddate) FROM Table1

;WITH CTE_Dates AS 
(
    SELECT @startDate AS DT
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DD, 1, DT)
    FROM CTE_Dates
    WHERE DATEADD(DD, 1, DT) <= @endDate
)
,CTE_Data AS 
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY BeginDate) AS RN FROM Table1

)
SELECT DT, t1.data FROM CTE_Dates d
LEFT JOIN CTE_Data t1 on d.DT 
BETWEEN t1.[BeginDate] AND COALESCE(t1.EndDate, 
        (SELECT DATEADD(DD,-1,t2.BeginDate) FROM CTE_Data t2 WHERE t1.RN + 1 = t2.RN))
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dc4ed/2)**

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @tblDateRange TABLE (
    Id INT,
    FromDateTime DATETIME,
    ToDateTime DATETIME
)
INSERT INTO @tblDateRange (Id, FromDateTime, ToDateTime)
VALUES
(1, '2023-01-01 10:00:00.000', '2023-01-01 10:00:00.000'),      --starts and ends in same
(2, '2023-02-02 00:00:00.000', '2023-02-04 23:59:59.000'),      --starts and ends in standered
(3, '2023-03-05 10:00:00.000', '2023-03-06 23:59:59.000'),      --starts in middle of another date
(4, '2023-04-07 00:00:00.000', '2023-04-08 21:00:00.000'),      --ends in middle of another date
(5, '2023-05-09 11:00:00.000', '2023-05-11 11:00:00.000'),      --starts and ends in middle of another date
(6, '2023-06-01 10:00:00.000', '2023-06-01 22:00:00.000');      --starts and ends in middle of same date


WITH DateRanges(Id, FromDateTime, ToDateTime, LevelNo, [Date], DateWiseStartDateTime, DateWiseEndDateTime)
AS
(
    SELECT 
        p.*,
        1,
        CAST(p.FromDateTime AS DATE),
        p.FromDateTime,
        IIF(DATEADD(SECOND, -1, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, p.FromDateTime) + 1, 0)) < p.ToDateTime, DATEADD(SECOND, -1, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, p.FromDateTime) + 1, 0)),  p.ToDateTime)   
    FROM @tblDateRange p
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        c.*,
        p.LevelNo + 1,
        CAST(DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DATEADD(DAY, 1, p.DateWiseStartDateTime)), 0) AS DATE),
        DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DATEADD(DAY, 1, p.DateWiseStartDateTime)), 0),
        IIF(c.ToDateTime < DATEADD(DAY, 1, p.DateWiseEndDateTime), c.ToDateTime, DATEADD(DAY, 1, p.DateWiseEndDateTime))
    FROM @tblDateRange c
    JOIN DateRanges p ON c.Id = p.Id
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DATEADD(DAY, 1, p.DateWiseStartDateTime)), 0) < c.ToDateTime    --date wise start datetime < range to datetime
)
SELECT *
FROM DateRanges
ORDER BY Id, LevelNo
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 30000) --max 32767, no limit 0
```

[image]