# For each day between two dates, add a row with the same info but only that day in the start/end columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, insert

I have a table, with types `varchar`, `datetime`, `datetime`:

```
NAME | START | END
Bob  | 10/30 | 11/2
```

What's a SQL query can I look up to find out how to make that table be?:

```
NAME | START | END
Bob  | 10/30 | 10/30
Bob  | 10/31 | 10/31
Bob  | 11/01 | 11/01
Bob  | 11/02 | 11/02
```

This is only ran once, and on a very small dataset.  Optimization isn't necessary.

Comment: what happened to year in start and end

Comment: Year can be anything, the idea is that START and END will be of type datetime.

Comment: Why are the `START` and `END` fields in your output identical?

Comment: Other parts of the product rely on a start/end date, my feature assumes one entry per day, so no start/end is needed, but must have it to satisfy other requirements.  If that makes sense?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

May be you need a `Recursive CTE`.

```
CREATE TABLE #dates(NAME  VARCHAR(50),START DATETIME,[END] DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #dates
VALUES      ('Bob','2014-10-30','2014-11-02')

DECLARE @maxdate DATETIME = (SELECT Max([end]) FROM   #dates);

WITH cte
     AS (SELECT NAME,
                START,
                [END]
         FROM   #dates
         UNION ALL
         SELECT NAME,
                Dateadd(day, 1, start),
                Dateadd(day, 1, start)
         FROM   cte
         WHERE  start < @maxdate)
SELECT *
FROM   cte
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
name    START       END
----    ----------  ----------
Bob     2014-10-30  2014-10-30
Bob     2014-10-31  2014-10-31
Bob     2014-11-01  2014-11-01
Bob     2014-11-02  2014-11-02
```

Comment: I have. (Name/ Start / End )
Bob 2014-10-30 00:00:00.000 2014-11-02
It should Be SELECT NAME, START, START AS END FROM cte

Comment: But what if I have two rows with different NAME, START and END dates

Answer (score 21):

You can do this with a recursive cte:

```
;with cte AS (SELECT Name,Start,[End]
              FROM YourTable
              UNION  ALL
              SELECT Name
                    ,DATEADD(day,1,Start)
                    ,[End]
              FROM cte
              WHERE Start < [End])
SELECT Name, Start, Start AS [End]
FROM cte
```

However, I suggest creating a calendar table and joining to it:

```
SELECT a.Name,b.CalendarDate AS Start, b.CalendarDate AS [End]
FROM YourTable a
JOIN tlkp_Calendar b
  ON b.CalendarDate BETWEEN a.[Start] AND a.[End]
```

Demo of both queries: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e5216d/2/1)

Comment: Other parts of the product rely on a start/end date, my feature assumes one entry per day, so no start/end is needed, but must have it to satisfy other requirements.  If that makes sense?

Comment: @HartCO Thank you! Your calendar table idea is brilliant.  I used a date dimension table I had already created for a Data Warehouse dimensional model.  Wanted to point out that your 2nd suggestion was a pretty straightforward approach. Thx.

Comment: Calendar table was fantastic for something I was doing, +1 for this.

Comment: Calendar table solution was perfect even after all these years, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The problem I had with this Question/Answer is it is for one record only.  I found a simple and effective solution in this answer post -- [SQL how to convert row with date range to many rows with each date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358959/sql-how-to-convert-row-with-date-range-to-many-rows-with-each-date).

The solution by "RichardTheKiwi" involves adding new date records based upon an Integer Table (list) and join to Source Table by evaluating the date range with `datediff` function.  You can pull an integer list directly from SQL Server master database (`SELECT master..spt_values WHERE v.type='P'`). This

Google the search term `sql spt_values` and there are many interesting blog posts about this table.  For example...

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 2](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)
- [Tricks using system table spt_values – SQL Server](https://www.sqlindia.com/tricks-using-system-table-spt_values-sql-server/)

Full Solution:

```
--NAME | START | END
--Bob  | 10/30 | 11/2

DECLARE @SampleData as table 
    (PersonName nvarchar(50), StartDate date, EndDate date)
INSERT INTO @SampleData
    (PersonName, StartDate, EndDate)
VALUES
    ('Bob', '2019-10-30', '2019-11-02')
    , ('Joe', '2019-10-30', '2019-11-05')
;

WITH 
cteSampleData_RecordAdded AS
-- NOTE: Range record converted to daily records for 'SampleData'
(
    SELECT 
        T1.PersonName
        , T1.StartDate
        , T1.EndDate
        , DATEADD(d,v.number,T1.StartDate) AS [NewRecordDate]
        , DATEDIFF(day, T1.StartDate, T1.EndDate)+1 AS [QDaysActive]
    FROM 
        @SampleData T1
        -- Adds a record for each date in the range
        JOIN MASTER..spt_values v 
            ON v.type='P'AND v.number BETWEEN 0 AND datediff(d, T1.StartDate, T1.EndDate)
)

select * from cteSampleData_RecordAdded
```

Results:

```
+------------+------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+
| PersonName | StartDate  | EndDate   | NewRecordDate | QDaysActive |
+------------+------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+
| Bob        | 10/30/2019 | 11/2/2019 | 10/30/2019    | 4           |
+------------+------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+
| Bob        | 10/30/2019 | 11/2/2019 | 10/31/2019    | 4           |
+------------+------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+
| Bob        | 10/30/2019 | 11/2/2019 | 11/1/2019     | 4           |
+------------+------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+
| Bob        | 10/30/2019 | 11/2/2019 | 11/2/2019     | 4           |
+------------+------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+
| Joe        | 10/30/2019 | 11/5/2019 | 10/30/2019    | 7           |
+------------+------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+
| Joe        | 10/30/2019 | 11/5/2019 | 10/31/2019    | 7           |
+------------+------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+
| Joe        | 10/30/2019 | 11/5/2019 | 11/1/2019     | 7           |
+------------+------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+
| Joe        | 10/30/2019 | 11/5/2019 | 11/2/2019     | 7           |
+------------+------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+
| Joe        | 10/30/2019 | 11/5/2019 | 11/3/2019     | 7           |
+------------+------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+
| Joe        | 10/30/2019 | 11/5/2019 | 11/4/2019     | 7           |
+------------+------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+
| Joe        | 10/30/2019 | 11/5/2019 | 11/5/2019     | 7           |
+------------+------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+
```

Comment: what if date range exceeds 2047 days?

Answer (score 2):

```
;WITH dates
 AS (SELECT (SELECT MIN(start) from table) as date,
     UNION ALL
     SELECT
            Dateadd(day, 1, date),
     FROM   dates
     WHERE  date < (SELECT MAX(end) from table))

SELECT name, date as start, date as end
from table
RIGHT JOIN dates on date between start and end
```

Comment: This will not work you cannot use `aggregate` on `recursive part` of `CTE`

Comment: That are subqueries, no aggregates on the cte.

Comment: in sub-query you have used Aggregate which is not allowed in `recursive part of CTE`

Comment: @Pரதீப் is right -- this isn't supported in SQL Server (the DB that the OP has tagged the question with). This is supported by some other DBs though, like SQLite

Answer (score 0):

The calendar solution mentioned in [Hart CO's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27489709/8213085) is always my go-to solution for this, but I'll add that you can create your own "calendar table" on the fly using recursive CTEs

This answer is slightly different to the other ones because it shows that you don't need to recurse over the initial table -- which makes this a more "copy-and-paste"-able solution

I would still recommend using a dedicated calendar table in your database in the vast majority of cases

### The "calendar table" CTE

In SQL Server, you don't *have* to include `FROM` in your queries, so you can spin up a "calendar table" pretty quickly between any dates that you want (almost, more details below):

```sql
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT CAST('2014-01-01' AS DATE) AS date_axis
  UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, date_axis)
    FROM dates
    WHERE date_axis < '2015-01-01'
)

SELECT *
FROM dates
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 500)
;
```

This creates a table with a single column, `date_axis`, and a row for every day between 2014-01-01 and 2015-01-01, inclusive

I've hard-coded 2014-01-01 and 2015-01-01, but you could use variants of this to work with whatever you need -- such as passing in values at runtime (if the query is run via a BI tool or script), or by building relatively off of the current date (if you only need a relative range):

```sql
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -365, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AS date_axis
  UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, date_axis)
    FROM dates
    WHERE date_axis < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
)

SELECT *
FROM dates
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 500)
;
```

The `OPTION(MAXRECURSION 500)` is [SQL Server syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#guidelines-for-defining-and-using-recursive-common-table-expressions) for setting up how many iterations you can do in the recursive CTE. Since each loop corresponds to adding a day, using `OPTION(MAXRECURSION 500)` would error if you needed more than 500 days (the default is 100, by the way)

The max you can set this to is `32767` which is just under 90 years -- if you need more days than this, you should definitely consider creating a physical calendar table instead

### Answering the question

To answer this question, another option for setting the bounds for the recursive CTE are to use some variables (in databases that support them) or any other supported mechanism to pull minimum and maximum bounds:

```sql
DECLARE @MINDATE DATE = (SELECT MIN("start") FROM example);
DECLARE @MAXDATE DATE = (SELECT MAX("end")   FROM example);

WITH dates AS (
    SELECT @MINDATE AS date_axis
  UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, date_axis)
    FROM dates
    WHERE date_axis < @MAXDATE
)

SELECT *
FROM dates
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 500)
;
```

Note that [Pரதீப்](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3349551/p%e0%ae%b0%e0%ae%a4%e0%af%80%e0%ae%aa%e0%af%8d) is right when they say that [overflowed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27489789/8213085) won't work because of aggregates in the (sub-queries of the) recursive CTE -- at least, for SQL Server it isn't allowed, so the variables approach would be more correct for the OPs database

The last part is then just joining the original table back onto the "calendar table" to get the output:

```sql
DECLARE @MINDATE DATE = (SELECT MIN("start") FROM example);
DECLARE @MAXDATE DATE = (SELECT MAX("end")   FROM example);

WITH dates AS (
    SELECT @MINDATE AS date_axis
  UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, date_axis)
    FROM dates
    WHERE date_axis < @MAXDATE
)

SELECT
  "name",
  dates.date_axis AS "start",
  dates.date_axis AS "end"
FROM dates
  INNER JOIN example
    ON dates.date_axis BETWEEN example."start" AND example."end"
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 32767)
;
```

This will now work for any number of rows in the original table and so I've whacked up the max recursion option to allow for a wide range of dates (but you might want to set a more sensible limit, if you go this route)

---

The full [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk) for this is available at:

- https://dbfiddle.uk/6ThD5Xbz