# Add a row with the same info but only that day in the start/end columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a table, with types **integer**, **datetime**, **datetime**

| ID | STARTDATE | ENDDATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 600097 | 2023-01-30 | 2023-02-02 |
| 602025 | 2023-09-02 | 2023-09-04 |

What's a SQL Server query can I look up to find out how to make that table be?

| ID | STARTDATE | ENDDATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 600097 | 2023-01-30 | 2023-01-30 |
| 600097 | 2023-01-31 | 2023-01-31 |
| 600097 | 2023-02-01 | 2023-02-01 |
| 600097 | 2023-02-02 | 2023-02-02 |
| 602025 | 2023-09-02 | 2023-09-02 |
| 602025 | 2023-09-03 | 2023-09-03 |
| 602025 | 2023-09-04 | 2023-09-04 |

I've tried using the following [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27489564/for-each-day-between-two-dates-add-a-row-with-the-same-info-but-only-that-day-i), but I'm having trouble when there are two rows with different IDs

This is only ran once, and on a very small dataset. Optimization isn't necessary.

Comment: What is your SQl Server version?

Comment: What have you already tried?  Please have a read of the [ask] section of the [help]

Comment: Join a calendar table/cte.

Comment: @Zhorov i use Microsoft SQL Server 2019

Answer (score 0):

For a *... ran once ...* calculation you have at least these options:

- A numbers table, generated using a JSON-based approach and an `APPLY` operator. Starting from SQL Server 2016 you may generate a serie of numbers using `OPENJSON()`. The idea is to build a JSON array with the correct number of items (`[1, 1, 1, ..., 1]`) and parse this array with `OPENJSON()` and default schema. The result is a table with columns `key`, `value`, `type` and the `key` column returns the 0-based index of each item in the array.
- A numbers table, generated with `GENERATE_SERIES()` and an `APPLY` operator. Starting from SQL Server 2022 you may use `GENERATE_SERIES()` to build the necessary serie of numbers.
- A recursive query.

Sample data:

```
SELECT *
INTO Data
FROM (VALUES
   (600097, CONVERT(date, '20230130'), CONVERT(date, '20230202')),
   (602025, CONVERT(date, '20230902'), CONVERT(date, '20230904'))
) v (ID, STARTDATE, ENDDATE)
```

Statement using `OPENJSON()`:

```
SELECT 
   d.ID, 
   DATEADD(day, CONVERT(int, j.[key]), d.STARTDATE) AS STARTDATE,
   DATEADD(day, CONVERT(int, j.[key]), d.STARTDATE) AS ENDDATE
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON('[1' + REPLICATE(',1', DATEDIFF(day, d.STARTDATE, d.ENDDATE)) + ']') j
```

Statement using `GENERATE_SERIES()`:

```
SELECT 
   d.ID, 
   DATEADD(day, s.[value], d.STARTDATE) AS STARTDATE,
   DATEADD(day, s.[value], d.STARTDATE) AS ENDDATE
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY GENERATE_SERIES(0, DATEDIFF(day, d.STARTDATE, d.ENDDATE)) s
```

Recursive query:

```
; WITH rCTE AS (
   SELECT d.ID, d.STARTDATE, d.STARTDATE AS ENDDATE
   FROM Data d
   UNION ALL
   SELECT r.ID, DATEADD(day, 1, r.STARTDATE), DATEADD(day, 1, r.STARTDATE)
   FROM Data d
   INNER JOIN rCTE r ON (r.ID = d.ID) AND (r.ENDDATE < d.ENDDATE)
)
SELECT * 
FROM rCTE
ORDER BY ID, STARTDATE
```

Result:

| ID | STARTDATE | ENDDATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 600097 | 2023-01-30 | 2023-01-30 |
| 600097 | 2023-01-31 | 2023-01-31 |
| 600097 | 2023-02-01 | 2023-02-01 |
| 600097 | 2023-02-02 | 2023-02-02 |
| 602025 | 2023-09-02 | 2023-09-02 |
| 602025 | 2023-09-03 | 2023-09-03 |
| 602025 | 2023-09-04 | 2023-09-04 |