# Postgres - How to convert row with an int range into intermediate rows from individual values from that range?

Tags: sql, postgresql

#### Initial input:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE(
   start_i INT,
   end_i INT,
   v REAL
);

INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (start_i, end_i, v) 
VALUES (300,305,0.5),
(313,316,0.25)
```

| start_i | end_i | v |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 300 | 305 | 0.5 |
| 313 | 316 | 0.25 |

#### Desired outcome:

Basically, I want to create intermediate rows with an additional column containing each value in the ranges shown in the initial table.

| i | start_i | end_i | v |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 300 | 300 | 305 | 0.5 |
| 301 | 300 | 305 | 0.5 |
| 302 | 300 | 305 | 0.5 |
| 303 | 300 | 305 | 0.5 |
| 304 | 300 | 305 | 0.5 |
| 305 | 300 | 305 | 0.5 |
| 313 | 313 | 316 | 0.25 |
| 314 | 313 | 316 | 0.25 |
| 315 | 313 | 316 | 0.25 |
| 316 | 313 | 316 | 0.25 |

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358959/sql-how-to-convert-row-with-date-range-to-many-rows-with-each-date) post, but it's for SQL Server, while I am interested in Postgres. In addition, I am not using a date column type, but an integer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `generate_series()`:

```
select gs.i, t.*
from t cross join lateral
     generate_series(start_i, end_i, 1) gs(i);
```

Strictly speak, the `lateral` is not needed.  But it does explain what is going on.  I should also note that you can also do:

```
select generate_series(start_i, end_i) as i, t.*
from t;
```

However, `generate_series()` affects the number of rows in the query.  I am uncomfortable with having such effects in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! Regarding your last comment, do you mean there is a performance downside to using `generate_series`?

Comment: @sqlquestionasker . . . No.  It is just weird to have a function in the `select` that affects the number of rows in the result set.