# Add column to table based on aggregations and ranges found in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given an initial table `t1`:

| i_t1 | tk |
| --- | --- |
| 400 | t1 |
| 702 | t2 |

and a second table `t2`:

| tk | i1_t2 | i2_t2 | v |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| t20 | 300 | 600 | 0.5 |
| t19 | 350 | 550 | 0.6 |
| t18 | 370 | 420 | 0.7 |
| t17 | 500 | 800 | 0.2 |
| t16 | 623 | 751 | 0.9 |

I would like to have the following result:

| i_t1 | tk | tot |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 400 | t1 | 1.8 |
| 702 | t2 | 1.1 |

This means that I add a column `tot` to table `t1` that contains the sum over all values in column `v` in `t2`, only when `i_t1` (from `t1`) is within the range `[i1_t2 , i2_t2]` (from `t2`).

#### Alternative #1:

It was to generate intermediate rows in `t2` corresponding to each value `ì` in the range. Then, group by that `i` and cross check `i` with the value in `i_t1`. This has been discussed in [my other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67404925/postgres-how-to-convert-row-with-an-int-range-into-intermediate-rows-from-indi). However, I noticed, that this will be adding a lot of rows (sometimes unnecessary, because there is no match in `t1`) in my case and creates a performance issue.

#### Alternative #2: (conceptual)

Go through `t1` row by row, select the corresponding value of `i_t1` (e.g. 400) and then pick up the value resulting from the query below:

```
select sum(v) from t2 where ((select i_t1 from t1 limit 1) >= i1_t2) and ((select i_t1 from t1 limit 1) <= i2_t2);
```

However, this requires to be repeated over all rows of `t1` and I'm not sure how to bring the result back to `t1`.

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this?

Here are the queries that can be used to reproduce:

```
create table t1 (i_t1 int, tk varchar(5));
    
insert into t1 (i_t1, tk)
values (400,'t1'),(702,'t2');

create table t2 (tk varchar(5), i1_t2 int, i2_t2 int, v real);

insert into t2 (tk, i1_t2, i2_t2, v)
values ('t20',300,600,0.5),('t19',350,550,0.6),('t18',370,420,0.7),('t17',500,800,0.2),('t16',623,751,0.9);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8bba3ffa346e31d2fa1313f97542fc92)

```
SELECT 
    t1.i_t1, t1.tk,
    SUM(t2.v)                                    -- 2
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON (t1.i_t1 BETWEEN t2.i1_t2 AND i2_t2)  -- 1
GROUP BY t1.i_t1, t1.tk
```

1. Join on your condition (`i_t1` between `i1_t2` and `i2_t2`)
2. Group and sum the join result

Comment: haven't thought about `i_t1` between `i1_t2` and `i2_t2` ! I think I went too far in my previous attempts. Thanks!