# How can I populate a table with all combinations of letters and digits from 01 to ZZ?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a `tableA (ID INT Identity(1,1) , Name VARCHAR(2))`

I want to populate the table with `name` values from `01` to `ZZ`: 01 , 02 , 03 , 04,. A1, A2, A3,.. Z1,Z2..

Every value will be distinct.

Comment: How is it random if every value is distinct?

Comment: I think your definition of "huge" may be flawed.

Comment: @Matthew exactly, it's funny how many people think "unique" and "random" are interchangeable.

Comment: I was using SUBSTRING(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(36), NEWID()) , '-', ''), 1, 2)   , but my bad about saying random. It is actually sequential.

Comment: Is the problem trying to convert an integer `ID` to a string `Name`?

Comment: yes, I can auto increment numbers but cant do alphabets

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you're looking for (you can always filter out any combinations you don't want by using the `WHERE` clause):

```
with characters as
(
select c = char(number) from master..spt_values
where type = 'P' and number between 48 and 57 or number between 65 and 90
)
insert into dbo.tableA ([name])
select
    c1.c + c2.c
from
    characters c1
    cross join characters c2
where
    c1.c + c2.c <> '00'
```

Please note that using `spt_values` in production code is [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273723/what-is-the-purpose-of-system-table-table-master-spt-values-and-what-are-the-me); a better solution is to use your own [numbers table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable). And if `name` should always be "distinct", you may want to add a unique constraint to the column, if you haven't already.

Comment: +1 - I also demonstrate the advantage of your own numbers table [here](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1) and [here](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2).

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @chars varchar(36)
set @chars = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

DECLARE @i1 int = 1
DECLARE @i2 int = 2

WHILE @i1 < LEN(@chars)
BEGIN
    WHILE @i2 < LEN(@chars)
    BEGIN
        INSERT tableA(Name) VALUES (SUBSTRING(@chars, @i1, 1) + SUBSTRING(@chars, @i2, 1))
        SET @i2 += 1
    END
    SET @i1 += 1
    SET @i2 = 1
END
```

Comment: Brute force, but it works.  I was thinking, though, if SQL had base functions out of the box this would be cake.  Base36 from 11 to ZZ and you're done.

Comment: A small point, but this solution includes `00`, which the OP doesn't want