# Replace every 2nd instance of character in string with TSQL

Tags: sql-server, regex, t-sql, replace

I have a field that contains a string of lat/long co-ordinates that define a geofence (polygon).  Each is seperated by a comma.

eg: 'lat,long,lat,long,lat,long'
eg: 148.341158,-21.500773,148.341406,-21.504989,148.375136,-21.513174,148.401674,-21.535247,148.418044,-21.532767,148.408867,-21.511685,148.414075,-21.508461,148.36968,-21.432567,148.349094,-21.438768,148.346862,-21.480187,148.341158,-21.500773,

I'd like to use this with the geography type in MSSQL (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933971.aspx)

```
DECLARE @g geography;
SET @g = geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((-122.358 47.653, -122.348 47.649, -122.348 47.658, -122.358 47.658, -122.358 47.653))', 4326);
SELECT @g.ToString();
```

This seems to require: 'lat long, lat long, lat long' ie: no comma between the pair.

I can't change the source data, as it's used by a vendor program.  I need to manipulate the string to remove every 1 out of 2 commas, or failing that, get regex working in TSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could roll your own parser like the following. It uses the commas in the string to find all of the lattitude/ longitude values. It concatenates all the values together using the pattern: lat long, lat long, ...

```
declare @list varchar(max) 
declare @result varchar(max)
declare @word varchar(max)
declare @splitOn varchar(1)
declare @wpos int
declare @cpos int
declare @wordCount int

select @list = '148.341158,-21.500773,148.341406,-21.504989,148.375136,-21.513174,148.401674,-21.535247,148.418044,-21.532767,148.408867,-21.511685,148.414075,-21.508461,148.36968,-21.432567,148.349094,-21.438768,148.346862,-21.480187,148.341158,-21.500773,'
select @splitOn = ','
select @result = ''

select @cpos = 0
select @wpos = 1
select @wordCount = 1

while (@cpos <= len(@list))
begin
    select @cpos = charindex(@splitOn, @List, @cpos)
    if (@cpos < 1) select @cpos = len(@list) + 1

    select @word = substring(@list, @wpos, @cpos - @wpos)
    select @result = @result + ' ' + @word

    if ((@wordCount % 2) = 0 and (@cpos < len(@list))) select @result = @result + ','

    select @cpos = @cpos + 1
    select @wpos = @cpos
    select @wordCount = @wordCount + 1
end
select @result as result
```

Which produces the following string:

> 148.341158 -21.500773, 148.341406 -21.504989, 148.375136 -21.513174, 148.401674 -21.535247, 148.418044 -21.532767, 148.408867 -21.511685, 148.414075 -21.508461, 148.36968 -21.432567, 148.349094 -21.438768, 148.346862 -21.480187, 148.341158 -21.500773

Answer (score 4):

You could use a [numbers table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819/sql-auxiliary-table-of-numbers) ([a *very* handy tool for many purposes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable), by the way) to find the positions of all the commas, then, using only the odd position numbers, replace the corresponding commas with spaces in a single SELECT statement. Here's what I am talking about:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT number, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number)
  FROM master.dbo.spt_values
  WHERE type = 'P'
    AND number BETWEEN 1 AND LEN(@coords)
    AND SUBSTRING(@coords, number, 1) = ','
)
SELECT
  @coords = STUFF(@coords, number, 1, ' ')
FROM CTE
WHERE rn % 2 = 1
;
```

In the above query, the numbers table's "part" is "played" by a subset of [system table `master.dbo.spt_values`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273723/what-is-the-purpose-of-system-table-table-master-spt-values-and-what-are-the-me). The [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) calculates the positions of all the commas in the `@coords` string, returning the results as a row set. The main SELECT is used an assignment statement. It takes every `number` in the `CTE` set and removes the character at the corresponding position in `@coords`, replacing it with a space character (all with the help of the [STUFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) function).

You can use this [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/22391) to play with the query.

Comment: It's worth noting a limit with spt_values is the max value is 2047. This may be an issue and for longer values for @coords.

Comment: @KarlMorosiuk: That's right, the system table was only used here as a quick and ready-to-use substitution to demonstrate the method.  For an actual solution, a dedicated numbers table would be preferred.

Comment: That's interesting

Answer (score 2):

This ended up my Solution:

```
DECLARE @WorkingCoordList VARCHAR(max) = 'some lat,long,lat,long string'
DECLARE @Processed INT = 0
DECLARE @CommaLoc INT
DECLARE @Count INT = 0

WHILE @Processed = 0        
    BEGIN       
        SET @CommaLoc = PATINDEX('%,%', @WorkingCoordList)  

        IF @Count % 2 = 0   
        BEGIN   
            SET @WorkingCoordList = STUFF(@WorkingCoordList, @CommaLoc, 1, ' ') --Convert comma to space
        END 
        ELSE    
        BEGIN   
            SET @WorkingCoordList = STUFF(@WorkingCoordList, @CommaLoc, 1, '#') -- Convert comma to hash
        END 

        IF @CommaLoc = LEN(@WorkingCoordList)   
        BEGIN   
            SET @WorkingCoordList = LEFT(@WorkingCoordList, LEN(@WorkingCoordList) - 1)  -- trim trailing ,
            SET @WorkingCoordList = RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(@WorkingCoordList, '#', ', '))) -- Convert all the hashes to commas
            SET @Processed = 1
        END 

        SET @Count = @Count + 1 
    END 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your regex works but if you preprocess the string with a regex, it might work with a global search and replace like this:

find:  `,([^,]*(?:,|$))`
replace: '`$1`' ie. space plus capture group 1

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the code :-)

I had a slightly different scenario however created a function using "chue x" code to add a character '#' at every 3rd ';'

```
/*** My select query ***/
SELECT        dbo.fn_AddEveryNthItem(a.MyString, ';','#', 3) AS Expr1
FROM            dbo.MyTable as a
```

Function is below

```
/*** Function to add character for every nth item ***/
Create function dbo.fn_AddEveryNthItem(@list varchar(1000), @splitOn varchar(1), @addChar varchar(1), @EveryNthItem int) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
declare @word varchar(max)
declare @result varchar(max) = ''
declare @wpos int = 1
declare @cpos int = 0
declare @wordCount int =1

while (@cpos <= len(@list))
begin
    select @cpos = charindex(@splitOn, @List, @cpos)
    if (@cpos < 1) select @cpos = len(@list) + 1

    select @word = substring(@list, @wpos, @cpos - @wpos)
    select @result = @result + @splitOn + @word

    if ((@wordCount % @EveryNthItem) = 0 and (@cpos < len(@list))) select @result = @result + @addChar

    select @cpos = @cpos + 1
    select @wpos = @cpos
    select @wordCount = @wordCount + 1
end
Return @result
end
```