# How to auto-add dates in column, SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

I'm very new to SQL Server and I want to have dates from today up to 30 days ahead of todays date in one column, which way is the most considered efficient and "correct" way? ( I'm not asking for code ).

I read that loops should preferably be avoided in SQL Server, is that correct? Also, I thought of solving the date-issue with using a logon trigger (adding 30 days ahead of today whenever a logon happens), anyone know a more efficient and "correct" way?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give a little more context? Why do you want to add 30 days? Why on login? What does your application do? This is to make sure we are not dealing with an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/161449)

Comment: Well I want to create a simple reporting solution, which would be directly linked to excel through add-in buttons, it would be a simple "to do list" or something of the like, and then I need to have a continuous column with dates

Comment: But do you really need a consistent "30 days into the future" set of rows in your table?  What exactly are the requirements here.  Would it be okay if, when you inserted a new task/date into the table, you also inserted additional empty rows for each day that passed?  Or do you really need this kind of set-up?  Can't you just deal with "sparse" data, with only rows for where you have actual tasks/events?

Comment: Thing is I want to go back and fourth in the dates, just like a usual calender but now in "database format", it's somewhat strange, but this is only for learning purposes anyway. I'm just curious how one would do this the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursive CTE to get sequential dates for next 30 days.

```
CREATE TABLE Dates
(
 allDates DATE
) 

;WITH MyCTE
 AS (SELECT getdate()                   AS ddate,
            dateadd(day, 30, getdate()) AS lastDate
     UNION ALL
     SELECT dateadd(day, 1, ddate),
            lastDate
     FROM   MyCTE
     WHERE  dateadd(day, 1, ddate) <= lastDate)

INSERT INTO Dates(allDates)
SELECT ddate FROM MyCTE

SELECT * FROM Dates
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c9d65/4/0)

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to do this would be a Job.  SQL Server Agent provides the ability to run any script you want on any interval you choose.  A very simplistic approach would be to create a job which runs nightly and inserts a row for [Today + 30 Days].

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are seeking 30 rows from a query with each row representing a date starting at today, and finishing 30 days after today.

There are many potential solutions for this that don't use a cursor/loop, for example

```
select
    dateadd(day,nums.number,nums.today) as a_date
from (
        select
          number
          , cast(getdate() as date) as today
        FROM master.dbo.spt_values as sv
        WHERE  sv.type = 'P'
                AND sv.number BETWEEN 0 and 29
       ) nums
```

<kbd>[see: this SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/1567)</kbd>

Note that query is using **master.dbo.spt_values** and some prefer not to use this ([refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273723/what-is-the-purpose-of-system-table-table-master-spt-values-and-what-are-the-me)). So instead you could use a small `union all` with `cross join` to generate the rows, or you can use a recursive  "common table expression" (CTE) as an alternative.

```
;WITH
Digits AS (
          SELECT 0 AS digit UNION ALL 
          SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL
          SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
          )
, Tally AS (
          SELECT [tens].digit * 10 + [ones].digit AS number
          FROM Digits [ones]
          CROSS JOIN Digits [tens]
          )
select
    dateadd(day,nums.number,nums.today) as a_date
from (
        select
            number
          , cast(getdate() as date) as today
        FROM tally
        WHERE number BETWEEN 0 and 29
       ) nums
```

Answer (score 0):

To get todays date + 30 days do this:

```
select dateadd(dd,30,getdate())
```