# Create a Range From n to 1 in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to create a range number from 1 to n.
For example, the parameter is `@StartingValue`

```
@StartingValue int = 96
```

Then the result should be:

```
Number
-------------
96
95
94
93
92
ff.
1
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?
Thank you.

Comment: [Generate a set or sequence without loops](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a Jeff Moden's [**Tally Table**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/) to generate the numbers:

```
DECLARE @N INT = 96
      
;WITH E1(N) AS( -- 10 ^ 1 = 10 rows
    SELECT 1 FROM(VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))t(N)
),
E2(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E1 a CROSS JOIN E1 b), -- 10 ^ 2 = 100 rows
E4(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E2 a CROSS JOIN E2 b), -- 10 ^ 4 = 10,000 rows
E8(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E4 a CROSS JOIN E4 b), -- 10 ^ 8 = 100,000,000 rows
CteTally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP(@N) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL))
    FROM E8
)    
SELECT * FROM CteTally ORDER BY N DESC
```

---

Explanation taken from Jeff's article (linked above):

> The CTE called E1 (as in 10E1 for scientific notation) is nothing more
> than ten SELECT 1's returned as a single result set.
>
> E2 does a CROSS JOIN of E1 with itself. That returns a single result
> set of 10*10 or up to 100 rows. I say "up to" because if the TOP
> function is 100 or less, the CTE's are "smart" enough to know that it
> doesn't actually need to go any further and E4 and E8 won't even come
> into play. If the TOP has a value of less than 100, not all 100 rows
> that E2 is capable of making will be made. It'll always make just
> enough according to the TOP function.
>
> You can follow from there. E4 is a CROSS JOIN of E2 and will make up
> to 100*100 or 10,000 rows and E8 is a CROSS JOIN of E4 which will make
> more rows than most people will ever need. If you do need more, then
> just add an E16 as a CROSS JOIN of E8 and change the final FROM clause
> to FROM E16.
>
> What's really amazing about this bad-boy is that is **produces ZERO
> READS**. Absolutely none, nada, nil.

Answer (score 2):

One simple method is a numbers table.  For a reasonable number (up to the low thousands), you can use `spt_values`:

```
with numbers as (
      select top 96 row_number() over (order by (select null)) as n
      from t
     )
. . .
```

Another method is a recursive CTE:

```
with numbers as (
      select 96 as n
      union all
      select n - 1
      from numbers
      where num > 1
     )
```

For larger values, you'll need to use the `MAXRECURSION` option.

Answer (score 0):

And another way.

```
SELECT N.number FROM  
  master..spt_values N 
WHERE  
  N.type = 'P' AND 
  N.number BETWEEN 1 AND 96
ORDER BY N.number DESC
```

More details on `spt_values` [What is the purpose of system table master..spt_values and what are the meanings of its values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273723/what-is-the-purpose-of-system-table-table-master-spt-values-and-what-are-the-me)

Comment: If you are using `spt_values`, take note that your query may not work if the number required is bigger than max `number` in `spt_values`. `tally` or `recursive cte` is safer

Answer (score 0):

```
Sequance of no's can be generated by following ways:
1. Using row_number by querying a large table and get the sequance.
2. Using system tables as you can see other people comments.
3. Using recursive CTE.

declare @maxValue int  = 96

; WITH rangetest AS 
(
    SELECT      MinValue =  @maxValue 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT      MinValue = MinValue - 1
    FROM        rangetest
    WHERE       MinValue > 1
) 
SELECT  *
from rangetest
OPTION  (MAXRECURSION 0)
```