# SQL Server table with default values

Tags: sql-server

Oh my god this is going to drive me nuts. There's a SQL Server table in, I want to say, model, or msdb, with a bunch of pre-populated values, including numbers, and some other random stuff like common strings and what not. I can't seem to construct a google search to tell me what it is. Can anyone help?

Comment: What is your question ? I read it more than 3 times still didnt understood

Comment: If you are familiar with SQL Server, there are several built in databases including `model`, `msdb`, `master` and so forth. In one of those databses, there is a rarely used table which comes default with SQL server which contains a bunch of boilerplate values including the numbers 1 through, I want to say 255, letters, symbols, and certain phrases. I'm trying to remember what that table name is

Comment: Is this `select * from master..spt_values` ? is what you are looking for

Comment: Yes! Thank you @Prdp

Comment: After reading you comment I understood what are you looking for. Question is not that clear at least to me

Comment: Hi, what is this table, and wts the use of it?

Answer (score 1):

Just echoing Prdp's answer, it was `master.dbo.spt_values`

Comment: Hi, what is this table, and wts the use of it?

Comment: @AbdulRasheed not much. It's a holdover from older databases. Truthfully I've never used it in my work, but I have occasionally used it for generating mock data or just to play around with things. There's a good discussion of it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273723/what-is-the-purpose-of-system-table-master-spt-values-and-what-are-the-meanings