# T-SQL return every other character from string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do you return every other character from a string from a specific starting position?

Example: starting at position 1

```
1050231
```

Result:

```
1521
```

Starting at position 2

```
1050231
```

Result:

```
003
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Late answer, but here's yet another option

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = '1050231'
Declare @P int =1

Select NewValue = (Select substring(substring(@S,@P,len(@S)),N,1)
                    From  (Select Top (len(@S)-@P+1) N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) From master..spt_values n1) A
                    Where N%2=1
                    For XML Path('')
                   )
```

**Returns**

```
NewValue
1521
```

Comment: This option worked best for my situation. I am not able to create a numbers table as I'm using a read-only account. It was easy to incorporate the subselect as a calculated field in an existing query.

Comment: @BobbyZimmerman Happy to help.   BTW - You should talk to your DBA about getting a numbers table.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Please note that [master..spt_values is undocumented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273723/what-is-the-purpose-of-system-table-master-spt-values-and-what-are-the-meanings), and though it seems unlikely to disappear some day, it still can. You can replace that with a stacked cte (Itzik Ben Gan style - you know - `WITH E00(N) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1),
        E02(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E00 a, E00 b),...`).

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yes, and I use that approach as well as demonstrated in many of my solutions.  That said, you can replace master..spt with ANY table of appropriate size.

Comment: True, the `row_number() over(order by (select null))` makes the actual table irrelevant. I didn't think about that. +1.

Answer (score 3):

Using a numbers table is usually the best way to avoid loops in SQL.
If you don't already have a numbers table, you should go read Jeff Moden's [The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/).

To create a numbers table, you can use the following script:

```
SELECT TOP 10000 IDENTITY(int,1,1) AS Number
    INTO Numbers
    FROM sys.objects s1       
    CROSS JOIN sys.objects s2 
ALTER TABLE Numbers ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Numbers PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Number)
```

Now that you have a numbers table, you can use it to select the specific chars from your string like this:

```
DECLARE @s varchar(20) = '1050231',
        @Start int = 1


SELECT Substring(@s, Number, 1)
FROM Numbers
WHERE Number >= @Start
AND (Number - @Start) % 2 = 0
AND Number <= DATALENGTH(@s)
```

Answer (score 2):

One method uses a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select @pos as pos, @str as str
      union all
      select pos + 2, str
      from cte
      where pos + 2 <= len(@str)
     )
select substring(str, pos, 1)
from cte;
```

Here is a [rextester](http://rextester.com/DRRAJ91603).

Answer (score 1):

The ugly way--a while loop, since Gordon gave the recursive CTE approach.

```
declare @string varchar(64) = 1050231
declare @start int = 1
declare @result varchar(64) = ''


set @result = @result + substring(@string,@start,1)

while @start < len(@string)
begin
    set @start = @start + 2
    select @result = @result + substring(@string,@start,1)
end

select @result
```

Comment: Not only ugly, but also a nasty RBAR approach. I wouldn't recommend that at all.

Comment: I was beat to the RCTE approach which is what I would use @ZoharPeled

Comment: Well, then, you should read Jeff Moden's [Hidden RBAR: Counting with Recursive CTE's](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/)

Comment: I have read it before, @ZoharPeled, and while it's not always a great performer, it can be great for some things. This question of the OP could be better handled outside of the DB as well, perhaps. I didn't assume the OP was going to do this on N number of rows. Maybe they were parsing a variable from an application where I think creating an additional table isn't worth it. Just *a* way is all. Best depends on the situation.

Comment: I totally agree that no approach is best for all circumstances. I also use recursive cte's a lot for local stuff on test databases, but I think that for production databases it's better to use the tally table approach.

Comment: Huge fan of tally tables for sure @ZoharPeled , and I keep Jeff's on an Admin Tools database deployed on ally instances along with Brent Ozar's scripts, nuggets from Aaron Bertrand, Adam Mechanic, all the greats that I know you also follow.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`STUFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=aps-pdw-2016):

```
declare @i VARCHAR(20) = '1050231';

select @i = IIF(LEN(@i) >= sub.s, STUFF(@i,sub.s,1,''),@i)
FROM(SELECT 1 s UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5) sub;
      -- any tally table

SELECT @i;
-- 003
```

---

```
declare @i VARCHAR(20) = '1050231';

select @i = IIF(LEN(@i) > sub.s, STUFF(@i,sub.s+1,1,''),@i)
FROM(SELECT 1 s UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5) sub;

SELECT @i;
-- 1521
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=de8229464c3024a792f20d8fa46ee863)**