# Increment values by column into rows-- SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following type of data

[image: Input]

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
    Room [NVARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
    iking INT,
    iqueen INT,
    isingle INT,
    idouble INT
)

INSERT INTO #tmp 
VALUES ('Marriot', 0, 1, 2, 1),
       ('Hilton', 1, 2, 0, 1)
```

I tried `Cross Apply` and `case` statements

I add data into temp table and wrote 4 cross apply functions for each column

1. King

   ```
   SELECT tk.Room, tk.iking, Type = CONCAT('BED', t.n)
   INTO #tempking1
   FROM #tmp tk
   CROSS APPLY
       (SELECT TOP (tk.iking)
           n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY o.object_id)
        FROM sys.objects o) t
   ORDER BY tk.Room;
   --select * from #tempking1
   ```
2. Queen

   ```
   SELECT 
       tq.Room, tq.iQueen,   
       Type = CASE WHEN ROOM in (SELECT  Distinct ROOM FROM #tempking1) 
                      THEN CONCAT('BED', t.n + 1)
                      ELSE CONCAT('BED', t.n) 
              END          
   INTO #tempQueen1        
   FROM #tmp tq
   CROSS APPLY 
       (SELECT TOP (tq.iQueen) 
            n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY o.object_id)
        FROM sys.objects o) t 
    ORDER BY tq.Room;
    --select * from #tempqueen1
   ```
3. Single

   ```
   SELECT 
       tq.Room, tq.isingle,   
       Type = CASE WHEN ROOM IN (SELECT Distinct ROOM FROM #tempking1) 
                      THEN CONCAT('BED', t.n + 1)
                   WHEN ROOM IN (SELECT Distinct ROOM FROM #tempqueen1) 
                      THEN CONCAT('BED', t.n + 1)
                   ElSE CONCAT('BED', t.n) 
              END
   INTO #tempsingle1
   FROM #tmp tq
   CROSS APPLY 
       (SELECT TOP (tq.isingle)
            n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY o.object_id)
        FROM sys.objects o) t
   ORDER BY tq.Room;
   --select * from #tempsingle1
   ```
4. Double

   ```
   SELECT 
       tq.Room, tq.isingle,   
       Type = CASE WHEN ROOM IN (SELECT Distinct ROOM FROM #tempking1)  
                      THEN CONCAT('BED', t.n + 1)
                   WHEN ROOM IN (SELECT Distinct ROOM FROM #tempqueen1) 
                      THEN CONCAT('BED', t.n + 1)
                   WHEN ROOM IN (SELECT Distinct ROOM FROM #tempsingle1) 
                      THEN CONCAT('BED', t.n + 1)
                   ELSE CONCAT('BED', t.n) 
               END
       INTO #tempdouble1
       FROM #tmp tq
       CROSS APPLY 
           (SELECT TOP (tq.isingle)
                n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY o.object_id)
            FROM sys.objects o) t
       ORDER BY tq.Room;
       --select * from #tempDouble1

   SELECT Room, Type, 'King' AS Descp FROM #tempKing1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT Room, Type, 'Queeen' AS Descp FROM #tempQueen1   
   UNION ALL
   SELECT Room, Type, 'Single' AS Descp FROM #tempsingle1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT Room, Type, 'Double' AS Descp FROM #tempDouble1
   ```

but I got

[image: Output]

My excepted output is

[image: Excepted Output]

Could you please help me

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Not many people are just going to write this for you. And posting images of data is not helpful, [why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)? You need to post some details like [this article](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/).

Comment: As commented, you will need to improve your question in order to get help.  A good start would be to add the statements that you have tried.  It also looks like you could potentially solve the problem with a [SELECT DISTINCT statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

Comment: You say you tried using `CROSS APPLY` and a `CASE` expression (it's not a statement). Could you include the code you tried when you update your post as per Sean's guide lines too please? Seeing your attempts often helps us understand your goal better, and sometimes it's a very small change that gets you what you're after; making the answer far easier for others to provide.

Comment: Please don't put your code in the comments. It is part of the question...not to mention the formatting is just horrible in comments.

Comment: To clarify Sean's comment, EDIT your question and put this info into it. Prefix each line with 4 spaces to render it as a code block. Please ensure your sql is nicely formatted/pretty printed and not just one big block of unindented/unformatted mess

Comment: Thank you Sean and Caius
Do i need to provide more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UNPIVOT operator to fix your solution. Try this script:

```
drop TABLE #tmp
go
drop TABLE #Hotel
go

CREATE TABLE #tmp
( 
     Room       nvarchar(30) NOT NULL
    ,iking      int 
    ,iqueen     int
    ,isingle    int
    ,idouble    int 
)

CREATE TABLE #Hotel
(
     Room       NVARCHAR(30)
    ,RoomType   NVARCHAR(30)
    ,Total      INT
)

Insert into #tmp Values ('Marriot', 0,1,2,1),('Hilton', 1,2,0,1)

INSERT INTO #Hotel
SELECT Room, RoomType, Total  
FROM   
   (SELECT Room,iking,iqueen,isingle,idouble
   FROM #tmp) p  
UNPIVOT  
   (Total FOR RoomType IN   
      (iking,iqueen,isingle,idouble)  
)AS unpvt

SELECT   Room
        ,RoomType
        --,'Bed'+CAST(Number AS VARCHAR) AS [Desc]
        ,'Bed'+CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Room ORDER BY RoomType,Number) AS VARCHAR) AS [Desc]
        ,'Bed'+CAST(Total AS varchar) [Desc2]
FROM #Hotel
INNER JOIN master.dbo.spt_values N ON  Total>=N.Number AND N.type='P' AND number<>0
```

Comment: Thank you for your response

We can use pivot,
But if iqueen = 2
we need 2 rows and type must be bed1 and bed2.

In your script it getting only one row iqueen and bed1

Comment: I believe my script already cover it(with Numbers table). Did you execute it?

Comment: I am sorry, I just noticed the desc detail. Still the script cover what you want.I have added [Desc2] to my final select script. Can you check it?

Comment: Thank You Ayzek. Its working

Comment: Ayzek, The code you provided is one-time use. If I re-run the code the bed+ value is incrementing and changing the values.
Could you please explain me the "INNER JOIN master.dbo.spt_values N ON  Total>=N.Number AND N.type='P' AND number<>0"

Comment: @VenkataJagadishPippalla Probably you got an error message because of the Hotel table. I have added an extra script to create Hotel first and insert into the table. the "master.dbo.spt_values" table contains numbers sequentially increasing from 0 to 2047. You wanted to multiply the beds if it more than one so I used this table to multiply it. You can find here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273723/what-is-the-purpose-of-system-table-master-spt-values-and-what-are-the-meanings more information about the spt_values table.

Comment: Gmus Thank you for your response. Now I changed the Row Number() to Dense_Rank() and added few more columns