# Creating multiple numbered rows in a table Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Desc**
I have table name: tableName and column name: columnName

**Problem**
I need to create 450 lines and number them from 1 to 450.

**I tried:**

```
For(int i=1; i<451;i++)
{
  INSERT INTO tableName (columnName) VALUES i
}
```

> for. exp.
>
> IdP
>
> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> ...

**Error:**
Could not find procedure

I don't know what procedure to use.

Comment: show the all related code! How you are creating connection/ command/ execute process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `SQL Server`, you can use *recursive* `cte` instead :

```
with cte as (
     select 1 as start, 450 as loop_end
     union all
     select c.start + 1, loop_end
     from cte c
     where c.start < loop_end
)
INSERT INTO tableName (columnName)
   select c.start
   from cte c
   option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

A tally is [far faster](https://wp.larnu.uk/speed-test-rcte-vs-tally/) at this than an rCTE.

If you wanted 450 rows, then this would work:

```
DECLARE @Rows int = 450;

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N 
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (@Rows) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3) --1000 rows, add more cross joins for more rows
SELECT I
FROM Tally;
```

Comment: Is master..[spt_values] will be better here? I want your remarks.

Comment: This won't result in a read from the disk, so *could* be faster, @SurajKumar . The easiest way to tell would be to test (with larger sets). Certainly if you are performing multiple cross joins to `spt_values` I would expect the above to be faster.

Comment: OK that may be the point of testing, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `master..[spt_values]` table. Here is the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4275271/10532500) link. This will work if you have master database and access to that database.

```
SELECT DISTINCT n = number 
FROM master..[spt_values] 
WHERE number BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

[Live Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=73e29d0f7a010809cd4e51619c0ee78d)

Answer (score 0):

Try using while loop:

```
declare @num int =1
while(@num <= 450)
begin
insert into table_name select @num
set @num = @num+1
end
```