# Replacing characters in a string with random ones

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to replace characters in a string from a column in a database with random ones. It is necessary that the characters be replaced with random ones of the same length, that is, there was a string Donald Duck - the result was the string A1B2C3 D4E5.

Here is a script that replaces characters in a string with random ones, but it does not replace with the same number of characters as were in the original string

```
SELECT id, (
SELECT STRING_AGG(LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), NEWID()), CHARINDEX('-', CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), NEWID())) - 1),' ')
FROM STRING_SPLIT(Name, ' ')
)
AS NewName
FROM dbo.[user]
```

Comment: In the above, you retain the space character. Are there other characters that you want to retain? Is it only alphanumerics you want to replace? If you had `Miles O'Brian` would you expect `AY1A5 Q'HA67N`?

Comment: Something like this perhaps: `SELECT object_id, name
 , ( SELECT STRING_AGG(LEFT(replicate(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), NEWID()), '-', ''), 10), LEN(value)),' ') FROM STRING_SPLIT(replace(Name, '_', ' '), ' ') ) AS NewName
 FROM sys.objects so`? Your code does incorrect LEFT, you want to have LEFT(LEN(value)) probably so your "random" word matches the length of the original, also you don't handle longer words well

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to implement some sort of a bespoke data masking technique.  Why not just use what comes out of the box - [data masking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking?view=sql-server-ver16).

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```sql
SELECT id,
    (
        SELECT STRING_AGG(
                   (SELECT CHAR(65 + CAST(RAND() * 26 AS INT)) 
                    FROM master..spt_values AS s
                    WHERE s.type = 'P' AND LEN(word) > 0
                    FOR XML PATH('')),
                   ' '
               )
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(Name, ' ') AS parts (idx, word)
    ) AS NewName
FROM dbo.[user];
```

This query should replace each word in the `Name` column with a random string of the same length, while preserving spaces between words. It first splits the `Name` column into individual words using `STRING_SPLIT`, calculates the length of each word, generates a random string of the same length for each word, and aggregates the results back into the `NewName` column.

The `FOR XML PATH` clause in SQL Server is used to concatenate rows of data into a single string.

About spt_values look: [What is the purpose of system table master..spt_values and what are the meanings of its values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273723/what-is-the-purpose-of-system-table-master-spt-values-and-what-are-the-meanings)

Answer (score 0):

Why not using

```
TRANSLATE(target, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 
your_favorite_random_string_generator(...))
```

?

e.g. in ORACLE, I would do:

```
TRANSLATE(target, 
        'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 
        DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('X', 26) || LOWER(DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('x', 26))
    )
```

giving

```
Abigail Ruddy   Gzet1em Ogwwk
Abner Everett   Qf83z 8f3z377
Abner Kenney    H1mcv Scmmc1
Abner Robbinette    Zamnw 2waaomnkkn
```