# Making automatic True False Generator

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am working on a project which is an automatic Quiz Assistant. I am using SQL Server I want to get random data from database to make other options of MCQ questions. Is there any method or query to get data randomly from database?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT 
    SomeColumn 
FROM 
    SomeTable
ORDER BY 
    CHECKSUM(NEWID())
```

Credits go to https://stackoverflow.com/a/121634/381995