# How can I add "X" rows to a table in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, rows

If I have a table, let's say Customers
and I want to receive from the user a number (Form) and create X rows in the Customer table.
Let's say the customer put the number 4 I want 4 new rows at the Customer Table.
How can I do this?

```
insert into Customer Valus ('Helen' , 36 )
```

Comment: Why would you want to create 4 empty rows?

Comment: Is this some sort of thought experiment or are you intending on doing this.

Comment: I'm curious -- is this for a school homework or something?  What real-world application could this possibly have?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a stored procedure and then pass the number of customers you want added. Something like this...

```
create procedure AddNewCustomers 
@NumberOfCustToAdd int 
as 

declare @counter int 

set @counter = 0 

while @counter < @NumberOfCustToAdd
begin
    //put your insert statement here
    set @counter = @counter + 1
end

go
```

Then, call the procedure passing the number of customers that the user requested...

```
exec AddNewCustomers @NumberOfCustomersToCreate
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want -

```
INSERT INTO Customers(Name)
VALUES(NULL)
GO 10
```

This will insert 10 rows which you can update later.

Comment: What a coinicidence ! I read a post whose first answer gave me the answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121243/hidden-features-of-sql-server

Comment: Limitation of this approach - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22412815/dynamic-sql-is-correct-but-sp-executesql-will-not-execute-it

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, this will generate 4 identical rows from passed in variables.  This will max out at 100 rows.

Un-comment and correct insert statement as you see fit.

```
DECLARE @I INT, @NAME NVARCHAR(10)
SET @NAME = 'HELEN'
SET @I=4

;WITH MYCTE
AS
(
SELECT @NAME AS NAME, X=1
UNION ALL 
SELECT NAME, X+1
FROM MYCTE
WHERE X<@I
)
-- INSERT INTO...
SELECT * 
FROM MYCTE OPTION(MAXRECURSION 100)
```