# Dynamic SQL is correct, but SP_EXECUTESQL will not execute it?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

The following code execute SQL n times.

```
PRINT 'X'
GO 10
```

I try to make this a dynamic codes with following query -

```
DECLARE @rows int 
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
SET @rows = 10
SET @sql =
'INSERT INTO MultiInsert(Name)
VALUES(NULL)
GO ' + CAST(@rows as NVARCHAR(50))
PRINT @sql
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sql
```

The SQL is a correct, but SP_EXECUTESQL give me an error as show below -

```
INSERT INTO MultiInsert(Name)
VALUES(NULL)
GO 10
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
```

How do I fix this error ?

Comment: Thanks for see my question. Chenqui.

Comment: I don't think you can terminate a batch from within SP_EXECUTESQL.

Comment: This is dedication to an answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22412307/how-can-i-add-x-rows-to-a-table-in-sql

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use `GO` in dynamic SQL expressions. `GO` is a keyword for management studio or other client tools.

Here's the MSDN documentation about `GO`, which explains how it's a client keyword only: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx. Notice this line in particular: "Applications based on the ODBC or OLE DB APIs receive a syntax error if they try to execute a GO command. The SQL Server utilities never send a GO command to the server."

Answer (score 3):

Well, @siride's answer shows you **why** it fails, and this is **how** you can fix it:

```
DECLARE @rows int 
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
SET @rows = 10
SET @sql =
'DECLARE @I INT = 0
WHILE @I <= ' + CAST(@rows as NVARCHAR(50)) + '
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MultiInsert(Name)
    VALUES(NULL)
    SET @I = @I + 1
END'

PRINT @sql

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sql
```

Comment: Thanks. I paste his comment here - 

You can't use GO in dynamic SQL expressions. GO is a keyword for management studio or other client tools.

Here's the MSDN documentation about GO, which explains how it's a client keyword only: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx. Notice this line in particular: "Applications based on the ODBC or OLE DB APIs receive a syntax error if they try to execute a GO command. The SQL Server utilities never send a GO command to the server."

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev Lamak has done it using while loop, not the way you were looking for i.e go. You must have mentioned in the question that you were looking for a way to insert values in a table multiple times. that can really be done the way Lamak suggested

Comment: @kashif I don't see anything in the question saying he couldn't use a loop. Was that on a previous question?, if so, this one should be updated and my answer deleted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this kind of query to generate 10 NULLs in one run:

```
WITH mycte AS
(
   SELECT NULL as VAL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT NULL FROM mycte  
)
SELECT TOP 10 Val from mycte
```

So you would do something like

```
DECLARE @rows int 
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
SET @rows = 10
SET @sql =

'WITH mycte AS
    (
       SELECT NULL as VAL
       UNION ALL
       SELECT NULL FROM mycte  
    )
    INSERT INTO MultiInsert(Name)
    SELECT TOP ' + CAST(@rows as NVARCHAR(50)) + ' Val from mycte'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sql
```

In this case a [recursive CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) with a single insert is used instead of a loop.