# What is the primary "means of programming and managing SQL Server"?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#T-SQL

> T-SQL (Transact-SQL) is the **secondary** means of programming and managing SQL Server.

I thought that T-SQL is the only means for programming and managing SQL Server, because it is the only SQL language used in SQL Server.

So what do possibly multiple "means of programming and managing SQL Server" mean?

What is the primary "means of programming and managing SQL Server"?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps using the Management Studio interface?

Comment: I wonder what the author meant by that, but from Microsoft, "All applications that communicate with an instance of SQL Server do so by sending Transact-SQL statements to the server, regardless of the user interface of the application." https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189826(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: Further down in the Wikipedia entry referenced by the OP, it states Mgt Studio as the 'Primary' means.  But there are quite a few ways...depending on your point of view..SQLCMD, etc

Comment: Added this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_Management_Studio to my answer

Comment: Now has a `[citation needed]`

Comment: @MartinSmith LOL good work.  For me - SSMS is usually my Primary way of using SQL Server...But certainly not all the time...Other projects may be more useful to use SQLCMD exclusively, or SQL Native Client.... It does depend.  So I'm glad you harassed Wikipedia - Keep 'em Honest!

Answer (score 0):

The Primary means of programming and managing SQL Server is from within the **SQL Server Management Studio** (interface)

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_Management_Studio) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio)

Some discussion remains about whether T-SQL is a subset of commands available in SQL Server.  ('Available' is a jaded word...Can any public User execute these commands directly?  Not entirely sure...But I am sure that the SQL System itself supports more commands than T-SQL purely as system commands are wrapped in Stored Procedures)

For curiosity - Use this trick

```
sp_helptext 'ProcedureName'
```

to reveal the real commands used in system stored procedures...(If Security allows it for certain SPs)

Comment: Thanks. Does SQL Server Management Studio not rely on or use T-SQL?

Comment: Perhaps not T-SQL exactly.  T-SQL is a trimmed down set of the complete command set I believe.  Besides the unpublished commands (used by the Developers only), there is a larger set of commands in SQLCMD I believe.   Yes T-SQL can do most things, but I think its still a subset of the full command set

Comment: What is the SQL dialect that SQL Server Management Studio use, if it is a superset of T-SQL?

Comment: One example...Say you have a massive T-SQL script - over 20 Mg of script perhaps...(including management scripts not directly part of T-SQL but able to be run via Stored Procedures) This will have to be 'executed' using SQLCMD as normal T-SQL features including OLEDB will not cope with the massive size of the script.  That is one example where SQLCMD is essential, above and beyond T-SQL itself

Comment: Good Question @Ethan ... Obviously the product has grown alot before and since owned by Microsoft...The only 'true' answer will come from the Developers, where I am sure, T-SQL is only a subset of the command set.  (Where the 'rest' of the commands are basically unpublished but usable within a script like T-SQL... Therefore technically not part of T-SQL so would comprise the superset.  I have used unpublished commands before but I forget which ones)

Comment: SQLCMD  is just another client tool that sends TSQL to the server. The only additional SQL CMD syntax is processed client side not by the server.

Comment: I think it is more than that @MartinSmith ..."You can use sqlcmd to execute database script files. Script files are text files that contain a mix of Transact-SQL statements, sqlcmd commands, and scripting variables. " ... By this statement sqlcmd commands are separate to T-SQL commands...from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/scripting/sqlcmd-use-the-utility

Comment: Yes they are separate to T-SQL commands. They only get sent to the sqlcmd utility. They don't get sent to the server.

Comment: And some system commands are available by using Stored Procedures in T-SQL, but the actual commands (within the SP) are not T-SQL commands...So we know there are more commands hidden in there somewhere :)

Comment: Interesting info here...(Although most of this is T-SQL) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121243/hidden-features-of-sql-server

Comment: I think a relatively simple example is that "GO" is not a T-SQL command but it is a command in SSMS.